# Execute command when job finishes

Tags: linux, bash, nohup

I would like a bash script to execute a command (which reports status information) when a certain job finishes.  I am running (with a script) a number of programs and send them to background using nohup. When they finish I would like to execute a script which collects information and reports it. Note that I am aware that I can have a for loop with sleep which checks actively if the pid is still in the jobs list. But I am wondering whether there is a way to tell the system to run this script e.g. by adding options to nohup.

Comment: Why not just put the command *inside* the script you launch with nohup?

Comment: Well, I am running programs (in a different language), but I could in principle write a wrapper script for each which would however be active during the complete execution time of the program itself.

Comment: Also take a look at the `wait` command.

Comment: You may find also [this post useful to read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570262/shell-get-exit-code-of-background-process)

Answer (score 1):

You could `nohup` a script that runs the command that you want to run and then runs the post-completion job afterward.

For example, create `runtask.sh`:

```
runjob
collect_and_report
```

and then:

```
% nohup runtask.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Start your jobs in a function, and the function in background.

```
task1plus () {
  task1 
  whenFinished1  
}

task2plus () {
  task2
  whenFinished2
}

task3plus () {
  task3
  whenFinished3
}

task1plus &
task2plus &
task3plus &
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
{script; report} &
disown -h
```

or, to make it conditional:

```
{script && report} &
disown -h
```

You could even do:

```
{script && report || fail} &
disown -h
```