# attatch existing process for sucess or fail commands?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, process

In Bash we can run programs like this

`./mybin && echo "OK"`

and this

`./mybin || echo "fail"`

But how do we attach success or fail commands to existing process?

**Edit for explaination**:

Now we are running `./mybin` .

When `mybin` exits with or without error it will do nothing, but during `mybin` is running, 
 how can I achieve the same effect like I started the process like `./mybin && echo ok || echo fail` ?

In both shell script and python programming way would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: more explanation is required...

Comment: only parent process can obtain exit status, i reckon. [this might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570262/shell-get-exit-code-of-background-process)

Comment: @avasal, I added some explaination.

Comment: @tuxuday, It's using a loop, system signals would be a better option.

Comment: how has a process failed if it is still running ?

Comment: @njzk2, if a proc fails and exits, run some program. Or if it successfully exits, run some other program.

Comment: you mean attach a action to the end of the program after you started it?

Comment: @njzk2 yes! So how can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

> *But how do we attatch sucess or fail commands to existing already running process?*

Assuming you're referring to a command that is run in the background, you can use `wait` to wait for that command to finish and retrieve its return status. For example:

```
./command &  # run in background
wait $! && echo "completed successfully"
```

Here I used `$!` to get the PID of the backgrounded process, but it can be the PID of any child process of the shell.

Comment: Does this work with any daemons in the background with the same uid/gid? How do I do this in program?

Comment: I believe only a parent process can retrieve the exit status. If you explain further what the end goal is, perhaps someone can give you more specific help. There's a chance this may be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: then how does `./mybin && echo ok` work? isn't `echo` a child-process?

Comment: When `./mybin` completes, the shell sees the return code and uses that to determine if `echo` should be run. `echo` does not see the return code. Both `mybin` and `echo` are child processes of the shell.

Comment: thanks. So what `wait` does is polling the pid to see if it stops? Any way to do this in system signal way? (no polling)

Comment: Yes, you can do that from ./mybin itself. If it is a bash script, use [`trap`](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html).