# check the return status of a background script

Tags: bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [shell - get exit code of background process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570262/shell-get-exit-code-of-background-process)

I have a bash scripts which runs another bash script in the background (`bash -i -c "blah &"`) the very first thing, and then continues with its own business!

The problem is how can I check at the very end, if the other script failed or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After launching script in the background, remember its PID:

```
do_your_job &
your_job_pid=$!
```

At the very end, wait for this PID. The result code of wait would be the result code of background script.

```
wait $your_job_pid
echo "Returned $?"
```