# Bash chek if error occured in subprocess (command &)

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting

I running mongodb instance from bash scripts and I need to show user-friendly message if mogngo will crash during startup for some reason.

so I have that sort of code

```
eval 'mongod --dbpath=$ABS_MONGO_DATA_PATH &' || printf "something bad happened"
```

but with that sort of notation error handler never called. But if I remove `&` sing, then after mongo initialization further script do not running because of mongod process waiting for a signals

How could I resolve that issue?

Comment: Looks very similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570262/shell-get-exit-code-of-background-process)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `eval` for this:

```
{ mongod --dbpath="$ABS_MONGO_DATA_PATH" ||
   printf "something bad happened"; } &
```

Instead of just running `mongod` in the background, run the entire command list in the background.