# Incorrect wget cmdline return code when starting in bg

Tags: bash, shell, wget

I have specified incorrect url in wget commandline and started the command in bg:

```
$ wget -q -O ubuntu.img http://cdffimage.ubuntu.com/precise/dvd/current/precise-dvd-i386.iso &
[1] 18039
$ echo $?
0
[1]+  Exit 4                  wget -q -O ubuntu.img http://cdffimage.ubuntu.com/precise/dvd/current/precise-dvd-i386.iso
```

My question is , why am I getting return code of `0` from `echo $?` ? Since an error occurred I should get return code of `4`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [shell - get exit code of background process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570262/shell-get-exit-code-of-background-process)

Answer (score 1):

You are running the command in the background. It hasn't finished when your shell gets control back. It can't give you the return code of a process that hasn't necessarily finished yet.

Also `$?` is documented (in the bash man page) as:

```
$?      Expands to the status of the most recently executed foreground pipeline.
```

Short of using `wait` to wait on the background job I don't know of any way to programmatically receive the exit code of a background job.

Comment: I get rc of 0 even after waiting for the command to fail. Can you please try that at your end?

Comment: @abc Like I said, once you run the command in the background I don't believe you can get the exit status without then using `wait` on that job/task to, effectively, stop having it be in the background. A background job is "detached" from the current shell in a way. And `$?` will never give you its exit status if it exits in the background (and I don't believe anything, other than that displayed message, will).

Comment: @abc Or did you mean even if you don't put it in the background?