# limit spawned parallel processes and exit all upon failure of any

Tags: bash, shell, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I'm running some tests in parallel by calling a process from a script.  Each process prints only to stdout > a file, and exits 0 iff successful (otherwise -1).

If and when a process exits with -1, I print something to its (or a related) output file (namely, the arguments it was called with), kill all other processes, and exit.

I have written a script using `trap "..." CHLD` to run some code when a subprocess exits and this works under certain conditions, but I find my script is not very robust.  If I send a keyboard interrupt sometimes the subprocesses keep going, and sometimes the number of subprocesses simply overwhelm the machine(s) and none of them seem to advance.

I am using this on my quad core laptop as well as a cluster of 128 CPUs, over which subprocesses are distributed automatically.  **How do I run a large number of background subprocesses in a bash script, limited to some number of them running concurrently, and do something + exit if one of them returns with a bad code?**  I would also like the script to clean up after keyboard interrupt.  Should I use GNU-parallel? how?

Here is a MWE of my script so far, which spawns subprocesses unhindered, annotated with what I think each part means.  I got the idea to use `trap` from [shell - get exit code of background process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570262/shell-get-exit-code-of-background-process)

```
$ cat parallel_tests.sh 
#!/bin/bash
# some help from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570262/shell-get-exit-code-of-background-process
handle_chld() {
        #echo pids are ${pids[@]}
    local tmp=() ###temporary storage for pids that haven't finished
        #for each pid that hadn't finished since the last trap
    for((i=0;i<${#pids[@]};++i)); do
                #if this pid is still running
        if [[ $(ps -p ${pids[i]} -o pid=) ]]
                then
                        tmp+=(${pids[i]}) ### add pid to list of pids that are running
                else
            wait ${pids[i]} ### put the exit code of this pid into $?
                        if [ "$?" != "0" ] ### if the exit code $? is non-zero
                        then
                                #kill all remaning processes
                                for((j=0;j<${#pids[@]};++j))
                                do
                                        if [[ $(ps -p ${pids[j]} -o pid=) ]]
                                        then
                                            echo killing child processes of ${pids[j]}
                                            pkill -P ${pids[j]}
                                        fi
                                done
                                cat _tmp${pids[i]}
                                #print things to the terminal here
                                echo "FAILED process ${pids[i]} args:   `cat _tmpargs${pids[i]}`"
                                exit 1
                        else
                                echo "FINISHED process ${pids[i]} args: `cat _tmpargs${pids[i]}`"
                        fi   
        fi
    done
        #update list of running pids
    pids=(${tmp[@]})
}
# set this to monitor SIGCHLD
set -o monitor
# call handle_chld() when SIGCHLD signal is triggered
trap "handle_chld" CHLD

ALL_ARGS="2 32 87" ### ad nauseam
for A in $ALL_ARGS; do
        (sleep $A; false) > _tmp$! &
        pids+=($!)
        echo $A > _tmpargs${pids[${#pids[@]}-1]}
        echo "STARTED process ${pids[${#pids[@]}-1]} args: `cat _tmpargs${pids[${#pids[@]}-1]}`"
done
echo "Every process started.  Now waiting on PIDS:"
echo ${pids[@]}
wait ${pids[@]} ###wait until every process is finished (or exit in the trap)
```

The output of this version after 2+epsilon seconds is:

```
$ ./parallel_tests.sh 
STARTED process 66369 args: 2
STARTED process 66374 args: 32
STARTED process 66381 args: 87
Every process started.  Now waiting on PIDS:
66369 66374 66381
killing child processes of 66374
./parallel_tests.sh: line 43: 66376 Terminated: 15          sleep $A
killing child processes of 66381
./parallel_tests.sh: line 43: 66383 Terminated: 15          sleep $A
FAILED process 66369 args:  2
```

Essentially, pid 66369 fails first, and the other two processes are dealt with in the trap.  I have simplified the construction of the test processes here, so we can't assume that I'll manually insert `wait`s before spawning new ones.  Additionally, some of the test processes can be nearly instant.  Essentially, I have a whole mess of test processes, long and short, starting as soon as resources can be allotted.

I'm not sure what's causing the problems I mentioned above, as this script uses several features that are new to me.  General pointers are welcomed!

(I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356100/how-to-wait-in-bash-for-several-subprocesses-to-finish-and-return-exit-code-0?rq=1) and it does not answer my question)

Comment: Killing a job running on a remote cluster when you press CTRL-C is non-trivial, so even if you find a solution that works locally do not assume it just works remotely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat arguments | parallel --halt now,fail=1 my_prg
```

Alternatively:

```
parallel --halt now,fail=1 my_prg ::: $ALL_ARGS
```

GNU Parallel is designed so it will also kill remote jobs. It does that using process groups and heavy perl scripting on the remote server: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_design.html#The-remote-system-wrapper

Comment: If I may clarify for myself:  I write each item of $ALL_ARGS to the file `arguments` (one per line), and then cat/pipe this to parallel, where `my_prg` is the process that takes the arguments (e.g. `sleep` in my example).  Can I still get output from the jobs that run, and print the arguments of the job that failed?

Comment: Yes you can get that.