# Getting results of parallel executions in bash

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a bash scripts in which I invoke other scripts to run in parallel. With the `wait` command I can wait until all parallel processes have finished. But I want to know if all the processes that executed in background in parallel executed successfully (with return code 0).

My code looks like:

```
--calling multiple processes to execute in backgroud
process-1 &
process-2 &
process-3 &
wait
--after parallel execution finishes I want to know if all of them were successful and returned '0'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [shell - get exit code of background process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570262/shell-get-exit-code-of-background-process)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wait -n` which returns the exit code of the next job that terminates. Call it once for each background process.

```
process-1 &
process-2 &
process-3 &
wait -n && wait -n && wait -n
```

Comment: My Bash 4.2.37 has no `wait -n`. Did you mean `wait <pid-or-jobspec>` (`wait [n ...]` in the man page)?

Comment: Yes. Even I don't have that

Comment: The ```wait [-n]``` thing can be found here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html

Answer (score 0):

wait -n seems the correct solution, but since it is not present in bash 4.2.37 you can try this trick:

```
#!/bin/bash    
(
    process-1    ||  echo $! failed &
    process-2    ||  echo $! failed &
    process-2    ||  echo $! failed &
    wait
) | grep -q failed

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo at least one process failed
else
    echo all processes finished successfully
fi
```

Just make sure the string "failed" is not returned by the processes themselves while having an actual success. Also you could run processes with stdin and stderr redirected do /dev/null with `process-1 &>/dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

I've written a tool that simplifies the solutions a bit: https://github.com/wagoodman/bashful

You provide a file describing what you want to run...

```
# awesome.yaml

tasks:
  - name: My awesome tasks
    parallel-tasks:
      - cmd: ./some-script-1.sh
      - cmd: ./some-script-2.sh
      - cmd: ./some-script-3.sh
      - cmd: ./some-script-4.sh
```

...and run it like so:

```
bashful run awesome.yaml
```

Then it will run your tasks in parallel with a vertical progress bar showing the status of each task. Failures are indicated in red and the program exits with 1 if there were any errors found (exit occurs after the parallel block completes).