# Bash - what is the while -process- checking

Tags: bash

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570262/shell-get-exit-code-of-background-process) the use of:

> while ps | grep " $my_pid "

Question: In this kind of syntax `while -command-`, what is the while loop checking, return code of the command or stdout?

Comment: It's checking the exit code of grep

Answer (score 1):

It's checking the return value of the process pipeline, which happens to be the return value of the last element in that pipeline (unless `pipefail` is set, but it usually isn't). The `bash` doco has this to say:

> `while list-1; do list-2; done`
>
> The `while` command continuously executes the list `list-2` as long as the last command in the list `list-1` returns an exit status of zero.

Elsewhere, it states:

> The  return status of a pipeline is the exit status of the last command

So this `while` statement continues as long as `grep` returns zero. And the `grep` doco states:

> The exit status is 0 if a line is selected.

So the *intent* is almost certainly to keep looping as long as the process you're monitoring is still alive.

---

Of course, this is a rather "flaky" way of detecting if your process is still running. For a start, if `my_pid` is equal to `60`, that `grep` is going to return zero if *any* of the processes `60`, `602`, or `3060`, are running.

It's *also* going to return zero if, like I often have, you have some number of `sleep 60` or `sleep 3600` processes in flight, no *matter* their process ID.

Perhaps a better way, assuming you're on a system with `procfs`, is to use something like:

```
while [[ -d /proc/$my_pid ]] ; do ...
```

This will solve everything but the possibility that process IDs may be recycled so that a *different* process may start up with the same PID between checks but, since most UNIX-like systems allocate PIDs sequentially with wrap-around, that's very unlikely.