# Can bash spawn multiple processes and report how many ran successfully?

Tags: bash

Is it possible in Bash to spawn multiple processes and after the last process finishes, report how many of the processes terminated correctly/didn't core dump?

Or would it be better to do this in Python?

(I'd ideally like to report which command failed, if any)

Comment: Related: [Get exit code of a background process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1570262/45249), in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29535256/45249)

Answer (score 0):

You can hopefully leverage **GNU Parallel** and its failure handling. General example:

```
parallel ::: ./processA ./processB ./processC
```

Specific example... here I run 3 simple jobs, each surrounded by single quotes and set it up to stop once all jobs are complete or failed:

```
parallel --halt soon,fail=100% ::: 'echo 0 && exit 0' 'echo 1 && exit 1' 'echo 2 && exit 2'
```

**Output**

```
0
1
parallel: This job failed:
echo 1 && exit 1
2
parallel: This job failed:
echo 2 && exit 2
```

By default, it will run `N` jobs in parallel, where `N` is the number of cores your CPU has, if you just want the jobs to be run sequentially, use:

```
parallel -j 1 ...
```

Obviously you could pipe the output through `grep -c "This job failed"` to count the failures.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a file with the commands:

```
cmd1
cmd2
cmd3
```

Then this will give you the number of failed jobs as long as you have at most 100 failures:

```
cat file | parallel
a=$?; echo $((`wc -l <file`-$a))
```

To get exactly which jobs failed use `--joblog`.

```
cat file | parallel --joblog my.log
# Find non-zero column 7 
grep -v -P '(.*\t){6}0\t.*\t' my.log
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy.

First run your jobs in the background. Remember the pids.

Then for each child execute `wait $pid` and see the `wait` exit status, which is equal to the exit status of the childs pid you pass to it.

If the exit status is zero, it means the child terminated successfully.

```
#!/bin/bash

exit 0 &
childs+=($!)
exit 1 &
childs+=($!)
exit 2 &
childs+=($!)
echo 1 &
childs+=($!)

successes=0

for i in "${childs[@]}"; do
        wait $i
        if (($? == 0)); then
                ((successes++))
        fi
done

# will print that 2 processes (exit 0 and echo 1) terminated successfully
printf "$successes processes terminated correctly and didn't core dump\n"
```