# How to check if a daemon successfully started as part of a script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Let's say I have this script:

```
start daemon1 &
start daemon2 &
echo "Running..."
```

`daemon2` can only be started if `daemon1` was started successfully.
if `daemon1` did not start successfully, then the script most be aborted

`"Running..."` should be displayed only if `daemon2` started successfully.
if `daemon2` did not start successfully, then the script most be aborted

How can I make this with a shell script ?

Comment: If `start daemonX` exits with a non zero value in failure, you can just do `start daemon1 && start daemon2 && echo Running`

Comment: Does the `start daemonX` command hang there after executing? Is that why you're using `&`?

Comment: I just tried this, it is not working. In fact, each daemonX blocks the terminal, that is why I run them in the background, and when I append &&, they are not run in the background

Comment: Yes understandable if the commands are blocking

Comment: May be the `wait` command can help, but it looks like it returns when the daemon is shutdown, not when the daemon has completed its startup process.

Comment: Possible duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570262/get-exit-code-of-a-background-process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose you capture the daemon's pid (process id) and then determine if the pid exists (after some delay in case daemon1 takes a while to process to start and crash).   So here is a way of achieving that (in Linux, I'm ignoring the 'start' in your commands since I'm not familiar with the windows cmdline environment ):

```
start daemon1 &
pid1=$!
sleep 3 # give daemon1 some time to get going 
if  
  kill -0 $pid1 2>/dev/null
then
  start daemon2 &
  pid2=$!
  sleep 3 # give daemon2 some time to get going 
  if
     kill -0 $pid2 2>/dev/null
  then
     echo "Running..."
  fi
fi
```

The necessary ingredients for this recipe are:

1. `$!` returns the child's pid (of the last background process run)
2. `kill -0 <pid>` is a way of determining if a pid is valid (in the process table)

Comment: I will go for that one, it makes the job. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can check the PID of the started process to see if it is running

```
start daemon1 &
P=$!
if kill -0 $P > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then 
    start daemon2 &
    P=$!
    if kill -0 $P > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
        echo "Running..."
    fi
fi
```

Untested code. Comment if something is not right