# How to check the status of a command launched in detached mode

Tags: bash, command, command-line-interface

I have a command (that would take a long time to run) launched in detached mode:

```bash
cmd1 &
```

After launching the command, I would like to get the status of this command (whether it has successfully executed or not).
I know that if the command is not in detached mode (run without the `&`), I can check, after the command has finished, if  `$?` equals to `0`, but what if my command is detached? (moreover considering also that I do not have to know if the command has finished or not).
Any ideas?

Comment: After launching, if you use `wait` command, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570262/get-exit-code-of-a-background-process

Comment: `{ cmd; echo ret=$?; } >& /some/logfile &`?

Comment: Thanks guys, indeed, the answer was in your links.