# Running programs in parallel using xargs

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, xargs

I currently have the current script.

```
#!/bin/bash
# script.sh

for i in {0..99}; do
   script-to-run.sh input/ output/ $i
done
```

I wish to run it in parallel using xargs. I have tried

```
script.sh | xargs -P8
```

But doing the above only executed once at the time. No luck with -n8 as well.
Adding & at the end of the line to be executed in the script for loop would try to run the script 99 times at once. How do I execute the loop only 8 at the time, up to 100 total.

Comment: That is what I initially wanted to do, but had to resort to xargs because I am on Windows. I was not able to get GNU Parallel running on Windows

Comment: Is that script calling itself or did you just confuse the names when you asked here?

Comment: Sorry, it should call another script. I will fix it

Comment: The answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321738/shell-scripting-using-xargs-to-execute-parallel-instances-of-a-shell-function is relevant here.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

From the `xargs` man page:

> This manual page documents the GNU version of xargs.  xargs reads items
>    from the standard input, delimited by blanks (which  can  be  protected
>    with  double or single quotes or a backslash) or newlines, and executes
>    the command (default is /bin/echo) one or more times with any  initial-
>    arguments  followed  by items read from standard input.  Blank lines on
>    the standard input are ignored.

Which means that for your example `xargs` is waiting and collecting all of the output from your script and then running `echo <that output>`. Not exactly all that useful nor what you wanted.

The `-n` argument is how many items from the input to use with each command that gets run (nothing, by itself, about parallelism here).

To do what you want with `xargs` you would need to do something more like this (untested):

```
printf %s\\n {0..99} | xargs -n 1 -P 8 script-to-run.sh input/ output/
```

Which breaks down like this.

- `printf %s\\n {0..99}` - Print one number per-line from `0` to `99`.
- Run `xargs`

  - taking **at most** one argument per run command line
  - and run **up to** eight processes at a time

Comment: Actually you don't need to put the arguments on separate lines; xargs word-splits. So `echo {0..99} |` would work just as well. `<<<{0..99}` doesn't seem to work; although `<<<word` is documented as brace-expanding word, it doesn't do so with any version of bash I have handy.

Comment: @rici Looks like a documentation bug then especially since the documentation for Here Documents *doesn't* mention brace expansion (and it doesn't happen there either in a quick test) though they also don't mention tilde expansion (which doesn't happen for `<<` but does for `<<<` so `*shrug*`). The expansions that do and don't happen in here docs and here strings are a bit odd to my mind.

Comment: How can you separate results from different runs with e.g. newlines?

Comment: Demo: `time head -12 <(yes "1") | xargs -n1 -P4 sleep` will run 12 `sleep 1` commands, 4 parallel. The command will take 3 seconds.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that `-P 0` will use the number of cpus on the system

Comment: You could also use `seq 0 99` to get the numeric sequence (with newline separators; works at least on linux).

Answer (score 15):

Here's an example running commands in parallel in conjuction with `find`:

```bash
find -name "*.wav" -print0 | xargs -0 -t -I % -P $(nproc) flac %
```

`-print0` terminates filenames with a null byte rather than a newline so we can use `-0` in xargs to prevent filenames with spaces being treated as two seperate arguments.

`-t` means verbose, makes xargs print every command it's executing, can be useful, remove if not needed.

`-I %` means replace occurrences of `%` in the command with arguments read from standard input.

`-P $(nproc)` means run a maximum of `nproc` instances of our command in parallel (`nproc` prints the number of available processing units).

`flac %` is our command, the `-I %` from earlier means this will become `flac foo.wav`

See also: [Manual for xargs(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html)

Comment: This answer was very helpful for me in that it explained how to use xargs rather than another tool 

Comment: Small footnote if you want to run multiple commands, you'll need to use `bash -c`. So for example maybe you wanted to `rm` the original file, you could do `bash -c "flac \"%\" && rm \"%\""`

Comment: It’s a bit easier to understand if you use the long options: for example `--verbose` instead of `-t` and `--max-procs=` instead of `-P`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use this simple 1 line command

```
seq 1 500 | xargs -n 1 -P 8 script-to-run.sh input/ output/
```