# bash: curl parallel requests in the loop

Tags: bash, rest, curl

I want to download more than 100k app definitions from api (json)
I have simple script for this:

```
BASE_PATCH="/media/sf_1/getappid/"

rm -rf ${BASE_PATCH}results

while read -r package <&3; do

            mkdir -p ${BASE_PATCH}results
            curl "https://api.test.com/v2/appid/${package}" -X GET -H "API-KEY: XxXxX-xXxXxXx" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --output ${BASE_PATCH}results/getappid.json

done 3<${BASE_PATCH}appIdId.json
```

And this is working, but it makes one request per loop - and it takes a lot of time (hours).
So my idea is to do it in parallel so.
1. Take first 5 ids from list (in file)
2. Start downloading those 5 json files
3. after it is finished take next 5 ids

Maybe someone have idea how to to this.
I want to stick with curl, now i want to download something, but probably soon I will need to use POST, PATCH or PUT (so tool need to have those options)

Answer (score 4):

With **GNU Parallel** maybe:

```
parallel -j 5 -a ${BASE_PATCH}appIdId.json curl "http://.../appid/{}" -X ....
```

You could also add `-X` to fetch as many definitions as possible per invocation of `curl` and thereby avoid having to create 100k curl processes.

Answer (score 1):

Gnu parallel as @Mark suggests, or `xargs`. See this question
[running-programs-in-parallel-using-xargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28357997/running-programs-in-parallel-using-xargs)