# ftp to multiple servers at same time

Tags: multithreading, bash, ftp

i'm currently working on a small script where i need to udate a file on multple servers, i have a long ip list of my servers and currently im using ncftpput to add the files to the servers one at a time.

i can't figure out how to start ncftpput with the next ipadress in my list so that i can have multiple updates running at the same time.

my list is just ip adresses:
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
...... until
192.168.0.150

what i need is the first ncftpput to access the first ip
the second number two ip
and so on for the amount of threads i need / system can handle

lets say 10 at a time and when the first thread finishes it just takes the next ip NOT taken by any of the other threads.

i hope i made myself clear on my problem and that someone can help me figure this out.

so far i'm doing it this way: (runnig one at a time)

```
while read ip; do

ncftpput -c -A -u "$USER" -p "$PASSWD" "$ip" "/usr/local/program/program.conf" < "~/addthisinfo" 2>/dev/null

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]

            then

                    echo -e "Here goes my succes test" >>/tmp/text_added

            else

            echo ""

    fi

done <"$pathtoiplist""/iplist"
```

in advance thanks.

-------edit-------------

i have full access to the server so i'm not restricted in and way conserning software to use.

Michael

Comment: You may replace `"$pathtoiplist""/iplist"` with` `"${pathtiplist}/iplist"`

Comment: didn't realize u need multithreaded one. You need to fork basically.

Comment: Is `ncftpput` the only tool at your disposal?

Comment: This answer should give you some solid ideas on using `xargs -n ..` . http://stackoverflow.com/a/28358088/620097 . Good luck.

Comment: i have full acces to the server running this.

Comment: using xargs still gives me a problem running xargs -n ... | myprogram <iplist    will that not just result in myprogram keep starting over with the first ip in the list ?

i need to be sure that thread 2 takes line 2 from the list and when it is done it takes the next line that we have come to say 13

Comment: why not a simple "&" at the end of the ncftpput line ?

Comment: when using the & solution will the if statement then run ?

Comment: I mean `myprog < iplist | xargs -n ...ncftpput  ...` , but I'm not sure what you have inside `myprog`, so YRMV. Good luck.