# Executing bash convert commands asynchronously

Tags: bash, asynchronous, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, gnu-parallel

I have a loop that cycles through a bunch of images that I need to edit with Imagemagick. Trouble is, it's slow to have to wait for each image to be edited before editing the next one. I want to execute each of the convert commands asynchronously not waiting for the last one to finish.Is this possible with bash? Here's a basic overview of what I have:

```
for img in *
do
  convert $img **more params here**
done
```

I want to execute that convert command asynchronously. So I can convert all the images at once. Is this possible with bash?

Comment: If you have GNU `xargs`, you could use it for running multiple commands in parallel.  Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28357997/running-programs-in-parallel-using-xargs

Comment: How does your system behave? resource-wise? is it capable of running commands in parallel?

Comment: Replace `convert $img **more params here**` by `convert $img **more params here** &` to convert **all** parallel.

Comment: @Inian To be honest with you I don't really know how to check that. It has plenty of horsepower behind it

Comment: @AlexKonetchy: Refer the simplest ways to achieve parallelism by doing as in Cyrus' comment above, or if you are more specific tools use the link shared in the first comment.

Comment: Okay, I guess the only added complexity is I need to know when the last convert $img & has finished. What's the best way to check that?

Comment: @AlexKonetchy: add `wait` in an extra line after `done`.

Comment: Thank you! If you add an answer Cyrus, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have many images, running hundreds/thousands of `convert` processes  in parallel is not going to work very well and you would be better off with **GNU Parallel** which will keep all your CPU cores busy without overloading the system - so if you have 8 cores, it will do 8 images at a time (though you can change that).

So, if you wanted to resize all the `JPG` images in your directory down to half their original size and rename them `resized-XYZ.jpg`:

```
parallel convert {} -resize 50% resized-{} ::: *.jpg
```

If you want to do all the `JPG` files and the `PNG` files and see a progress meter as they run:

```
parallel --progress convert {} -resize 50% resized-{} ::: *.jpg *.png
```

If you want to do specifically 8 at a time, use:

```
parallel -j8 ....
```

If you want to see what the command is going to do, without actually doing anything:

```
parallel --dry-run ...
```

Comment: Instead of `--progress` try `--bar`. See which one you like better.

Comment: This, by the way, has worked wonders. I can convert 200 images in about 2 seconds using this method.

Comment: **GNU Parallel** is brilliant - kudos to @OleTange who develops it.