# How to run multiple bash scripts parallely using gnu parallel or any other

Tags: bash, shell, gnu-parallel

I want to run multiple bash scripts parallelly.

(Already posted a question regarding this but i didn't get any proper solution that's why i'm posting again)

Example of my scripts : ./test1.sh $1 , ./test2.sh $1 , ./test3.sh $1   etc

I tried this way

`parallel ::: "~/path/test1.sh $1" "~/path/test2.sh $1"`

Not getting the results properly, if the test1.sh executes first,then the test2.sh getting stopped.

Can anyone help me with this !

Thanks

Comment: `./test1.sh "$1" & ./test2.sh "$1" & ./test3.sh "$1"`?

Comment: What is `$1`? If your scripts are `./test1.sh`, why are you running `~/path/test1.sh` ?

Comment: How about `parallel {} MYSTERIOUSPARAMETER ::: ./test*.sh`

Comment: You can consider xargs as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/28358088/3220113

Comment: Please make an MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Without that it is hard to help.