# Check if PID exists in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, pid

I want to stall the execution of my BASH script until a process is closed (I have the PID stored in a variable). I'm thinking

```
while [PID IS RUNNING]; do
sleep 500
done
```

Most of the examples I have seen use /dev/null which seems to require root. Is there a way to do this without requiring root?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356100/how-to-wait-in-bash-for-several-subprocesses-to-finish-and-return-exit-code-0-w

Comment: Please see [Process Management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement). Can you show an example of using `/dev/null` which requires root? I can't imagine how that would be the case or how it would be applicable to this case.

Comment: What usage of /dev/null seems to require root? Can't think of any.

Answer (score 40):

`kill -s 0 $pid` will return success if `$pid` is running, failure otherwise, without actually sending a signal to the process, so you can use that in your `if` statement directly.

`wait $pid` will wait on that process, replacing your whole loop.

Comment: Thanks. Here is my current code: `while sleep 1; do kill -0 $PIDD || break; done`.

Comment: Note: `kill -0 $pid` only works for processes you own. `ps -p $pid` will work for any process.

Comment: Note: `wait $pid` only works if you are the parent of `$pid`.

Answer (score 26):

It seems like you want

```
wait $pid
```

which will return when `$pid` finishes.

Otherwise you can use

```
ps -p $pid
```

to check if the process is still alive (this is more effective than `kill -0 $pid` because it will work even if you don't own the pid).

Comment: Note: `wait` only works if `$pid` is a child process of the shell. That is probably often the case in these scenarios, but not always.

Comment: `wait` is not useful when scripting. If the goal is to quickly determine if a pid exists, then do something, wait would have be be bg which is inefficient. The second solution is better. Include removing the header and its usable: `ps -p $pid | tail -n +2`

Comment: Dave: The question literally states: "I want to stall the execution of my BASH script until a process is closed" which is exactly what `wait` does. `wait` is perfectly usable in a script, I have used it many times! It simply depends what your use-case is.

Answer (score 10):

You might look for the presence of `/proc/YOUR_PID` directory.

Comment: That's okay, if you are running the script in Linux only. To assure compatibility, it's better to use `kill -s` trick given above.

Comment: In my tests, I see that directory hang around for a short time after the process has died

Answer (score 8):

`ps --pid $pid &>/dev/null`

returns 0 if it exists, 1 otherwise

Comment: The `--pid` option for `ps` may work in your operating system, but it doesn't work in mine.  Did the OP mention what OS he's running?  If not, you should qualify answers you provide which are OS-specific and non-portable.

Answer (score 3):

I always use the following 
`tail -f /dev/null --pid $PID`. It doesn't require explicit loop and isn't limited to your shell's children pids only.

Comment: The `tail` command on FreeBSD and OSX does not include a `--pid` option. If the OP isn't asking about a particular operating system, you should qualify any answers you provide which are platform-specific.