# Capturing output of asynchronous bash commands?

Tags: multithreading, bash, scripting, asynchronous

Is it possible to do something like this in bash?

```
output=$(echo hello; sleep 10) &
pid=$!
# run some more commands
wait $pid
echo $output
```

I would like to run multiple commands in parallel, capturing their output. I'd like to do it in a "clean" way - not writing to temporary files etc.

Comment: probably try reading from the stdout files fd = 1 of the from `/proc/<process_id>/fd/1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a named pipe to communicate between parent and child, see [man mkfifo](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo) for details. Parent can use *read* command to fetch data from the pipe.

Comment: There are some subtleties to how you collect the processes too, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26240420/2492.