# How do you make a bash script wait for second script to finish before continuing?

Tags: bash

I have a script that does some processing and then will call another relevant script. This second script may not be the same each time.

How do I call the second script from bash and have my first script wait until it is finished before it continues. I also want to run the second script in its own window.

Currently I have:

```
gnome-terminal -x sh second.sh
```

But the first script continues whilst second is running.

Comment: Strange. Running `gnome-terminal -x sleep 5` waits for the terminal to finish.

Comment: I think I see the same behaviour as @choroba but using as larsmans typed in question below! :S

Comment: @choroba: on my system it doesn't. Behavior might differ per GNOME version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to wait in bash for several subprocesses to finish and return exit code !=0 when any subprocess ends with code !=0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356100/how-to-wait-in-bash-for-several-subprocesses-to-finish-and-return-exit-code-0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem here is not with `bash` (which processes commands in sequence unless you explicitly tell it not to using `&`), it's with `gnome-terminal`, which hands off your execution request to a background process and then terminates the one you called.

As far as I can tell, there is no way to get `gnome-terminal` to behave differently. An alternative might  be to use `xterm`, which is synchronous by default.

Comment: I was originally trying to use xterm, but couldn't ever get a second window to appear? any idea how to do that?

Comment: +1. Seems GNOME Terminal forks, like many other modern X11 programs.