# Calling shell functions with xargs

Tags: bash, sh, xargs

I am trying to use xargs to call a more complex function in parallel.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo_var(){
    echo $1
    return 0
}
seq -f "n%04g" 1 100 |xargs -n 1 -P 10 -i echo_var {} 
exit 0
```

This returns the error

```
xargs: echo_var: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas on how I can use xargs to accomplish this, or any other solution(s) would be welcome.

Comment: Danger, user1148366, Danger! Don't use bash for parallel programming- you will run into so many problems. Use C/C++ and pthreads, or Java threads, or anything that makes you think long and hard about what you're doing, because parallel programming takes a lot of thought to get right.

Comment: @DavidSouther If the tasks are independent, such as convert all these picture files to png, then don't worry. It is when you have synchronisation (beyond wait for all to finish)  and communication that it gets messy.

Comment: @DavidSouther - I am a long time Java dev and I have been working in groovy of late. And I continue to tell people: Friends don't let friends write bash script. And yet, I find myself looking at this post/solution because (sad face :( ) I am engaged in parallel processing in bash. I could readily do it in groovy/java. Bad!

Comment: Also discussed in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158564/how-to-use-defined-function-with-xargs

Comment: @DavidSouther would love to hear some specific examples because bash is probably the only popular language that has sane parallel computation handling. Pipelines are so intuitive, people using them don't even know they're writing a parallel program. Meanwhile I couldn't imagine a worse language than C in which to do it.

Comment: You know... I have no idea what I was saying 12 years ago in a comment on stack overflow. But definitely was along the lines of what @ChristianBongiorno said- easy to get started, difficult to impossible to handle complex synchronization. For the record, I'd still stick with "are you sure bash is the right tool for your problem" but then I'd suggest Rust in the absence of existing implementation constraints over C.

Answer (score 252, accepted):

Exporting the function should do it (untested):

```
export -f echo_var
seq -f "n%04g" 1 100 | xargs -n 1 -P 10 -I {} bash -c 'echo_var "$@"' _ {}
```

You can use the builtin `printf` instead of the external `seq`:

```
printf "n%04g\n" {1..100} | xargs -n 1 -P 10 -I {} bash -c 'echo_var "$@"' _ {}
```

Also, using `return 0` and `exit 0` like that masks any error value that might be produced by the command preceding it. Also, if there's no error, it's the default and thus somewhat redundant.

@phobic mentions that the Bash command ***could*** be simplified to

```
bash -c 'echo_var "{}"'
```

moving the `{}` directly inside it. **But** it's **vulnerable to command injection** as pointed out by @Sasha.

Here is an example why you **should not use** the embedded format:

```
$ echo '$(date)' | xargs -I {} bash -c 'echo_var "{}"'
Sun Aug 18 11:56:45 CDT 2019
```

Another example of **why not**:

```
echo '\"; date\"' | xargs -I {} bash -c 'echo_var "{}"'
```

This is what is output **using the safe format**:

```
$ echo '$(date)' | xargs -I {} bash -c 'echo_var "$@"' _ {}
$(date)
```

This is comparable to using [parameterized](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) SQL [queries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) to avoid [injection](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Parametrized_SQL_statement).

I'm using `date` in a command substitution or in escaped quotes here instead of the `rm` command used in Sasha's comment since it's non-destructive.

Comment: A bit more discussion: xargs executes a completely new instance of the process named. In this case, you provide the name `echo_var`, which is a function in this script, not a process (program) in your PATH. What Dennis' solution does is export the function for child bash processes to use, then forks to the subprocess and executes there.

Comment: what is the significance of `_` and ``\`` , without them it wasn't working for me

Comment: @Hashbrown: The underscore (`_`) provides a place holder for `argv[0]` (`$0`) and almost anything could be used there. I think I added the backslash-semicolon (`\;`) because of its use in terminating the `-exec` clause in `find`, but it works for me without it here. In fact, if the function were to use `$@` instead of `$1` then it would see the semicolon as a parameter, so it should be omitted.

Comment: -i argument to xargs is since been deprecated. Use -I (capital i) instead.

Comment: You can simplify this by including the argument from xargs in the command string for bash with `bash -c 'echo_var "{}"'`. So you do not need the _ {} at the end.

Comment: Adding to the `-i` vs. `-I` issue mentioned by @Nicolai: [POSIX does not even mention](https://man.openbsd.org/POSIX-2013/xargs) `-i`, providing a stronger reason than "just" deprecation.

Comment: Would you be so kind to explain me this syntax `-I {} bash -c 'echo_var "$@"' _ {}`, please?

Comment: @Daniele: `-I {}` sets the replacement string to a set of curly braces. In the command processed by `xargs`, the replacement string will be replaced by the arguments, each in turn. the rest of the part that you quoted is invoking Bash to run the function `echo_var` with all the arguments it receives (`$@`). The underscore at the end stands for `argv[0]` as mentioned in an earlier comment. Finally, the curly braces at the end is where the arguments passed to `xargs` (by `seq` or `printf` in this case) are substituted and then passed to the `bash` command.

Comment: @phobic, `bash -c 'echo_var "{}"'` is bad idea. If the input line contains `"`, it won't be properly escaped. E.g. piping the `hello"; rm -rf "/` string to `xargs -I {} bash -c 'echo_var "{}"'` would lead to `bash -c 'echo_var "hello"; rm -rf "/"'`.

Comment: I had confused with the arguments `_  {}`  in the command, now I understand it, it is explained in the bash man page, see explanation for `-c` option.

Comment: @poige: Why do you say that? `type -a printf` outputs `printf is a shell builtin \n
printf is /usr/bin/printf \n printf is /bin/printf` (which varies depending on the OS). It _is_ a builtin and it's _also_ an external executable. It's also documented in the Shell Builtin Commands section of `man bash`. The builtin is preferentially run (as evidenced by the order of the output of `type -a`). In order to run the external executable, you must specify the path (e.g. `/usr/bin/printf '%s\n' "$string"`) or use other techniques (e.g.`env printf ...`).

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, yeah, already noted, your reply was literally one minute earlier than I came to drop the comment. )

Comment: @DennisWilliamson This solution doesn't work on my linux machine (only works on my Mac machine) b/c on the linux system `-I {}` overrides `-n 1`. My xargs version on linux is: `xargs (GNU findutils) 4.5.11`

Comment: Your answer can be simplified & in the process it starts working with the `-n 1` argument (which it currently doesn't). Details are in my answer.

Answer (score 17):

Something like this should work also:

```
function testing() { sleep $1 ; }
echo {1..10} | xargs -n 1 | xargs -I@ -P4 bash -c "$(declare -f testing) ; testing @ ; echo @ "
```

Comment: In general, this would break on shell special characters (e.g. `|`, `#`) and ignore white space in input. Instead of letting bash treat the input as code, I suggest letting xargs pass them as-is. `echo {1..10} | xargs -n 1 -P4 bash -c "$(declare -f testing);"' testing "$@"; echo "$@";' argv0`

Answer (score 4):

Seems I can't make comments :-(

I was wondering about the focus on

```
bash -c 'echo_var "$@"' _ {}
vs
bash -c 'echo_var "{}"'
```

The 1st substitutes the {} as an arg to bash while the 2nd as an arg to the function. The fact that example 1 doesn't expand the $(date) is simply a a side effect.

If you don't want the functions args expanded , use single single quotes rather than double. To avoid messy nesting , use double quote (expand args on the other one)

```
$ echo '$(date)' | xargs -0 -L1 -I {} bash -c 'printit "{}"'
Fri 11 Sep 17:02:24 BST 2020

$ echo '$(date)' | xargs -0 -L1 -I {} bash -c "printit '{}'"
$(date)
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is bad practice, but you if you are defining functions in a `.bashrc` or other script, you can wrap the file or at least the function definitions with a setting of `allexport`:

```
set -o allexport

function funcy_town {
  echo 'this is a function'
}
function func_rock {
  echo 'this is a function, but different'
}
function cyber_func {
  echo 'this function does important things'
}
function the_man_from_funcle {
  echo 'not gonna lie'
}
function funcle_wiggly {
  echo 'at this point I\'m doing it for the funny names'
}
function extreme_function {
  echo 'goodbye'
}

set +o allexport
```

Answer (score 2):

@DennisWilliamson 's answer fails to use the `-n 1` argument correctly **& therefore fails when the input is a sequence on one line**, e.g.:

DennisWilliamson's Method:

```
export -f echo_var 
echo 1 2 3 | xargs -n 1 -P 10 -I {} bash -c 'echo_var "$@"' _ {}
```

Output (Incorrect, ignores -n 1):

```
1 2 3
```

**But I found a robust & *simpler* method which works with `-n 1`**!

My Simpler/Robust Method (drops `-I {}` & trailing `{}`):

```
export -f echo_var;
echo 1 2 3 | xargs -n 1 -P 10 bash -c 'echo_var "$@"' _
```

Output (Correct):

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own version of `xargs` that can handle functions.

usage example:

```bash
function my_echo() {
    echo "$@"
}
echo 1 2 3 | xargs my_echo
# xargs: my_echo: No such file or directory
echo 1 2 3 | xargs2 my_echo
# 1 2 3
```

`xargs2` itself:

```bash
is_function() {
  if [[ $(type -t "${1?ensure_is_a_function: provide a command}") == "function" ]]; then
    return 0
  else
    return 1
  fi
}

function xargs2 {
  if is_function "$1"; then
    export -f "${1?}" # so subprocess bash can see it
  else
    echo "xargs2: use xargs" >&2
    return 1
  fi
  ARGS=$(printf "%q " "$@") # escape
  cat </dev/stdin | xargs bash -c "$ARGS \$@" _
}
```