# Pipe to export command

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, pipeline, xargs

Why does `export` fail when used as the last step in a command pipeline?

```
echo FOO=bar | xargs export
# => xargs: export: No such file or directory
```

I can rewrite it this way to accomplish what I want:

```
export `echo FOO=bar`
```

But why can't I use `export` in the first way?

Comment: To answer the followup question ("how can I get `xargs` to work with functions?"): http://stackoverflow.com/q/11003418/1004889

Comment: Note the following will work `export "$(cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3)"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

export is a shell builtin and xargs expects an actual binary.