# How can I pass each filename to my function?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I'm trying to write a simple function that will allow me to interactively unstage files from Git. Here's what I have so far:

```
reset_or_keep () {
  echo "Received $1"
}

interactive_reset () {
  local mods=
  mods=`git status --porcelain | sed -e "s/^[A-Z][ \t]*//g" | xargs reset_or_keep`
}
```

However, I receive this error:

```
xargs: reset_or_keep: No such file or directory
```

I would like that reset_or_keep is called once for every entry in `git status --porcelain`

Comment: I think this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003418/calling-functions-with-xargs-within-a-bash-script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to effectively reimplement `xargs` directly in bash using `read`:

```
#!/bin/sh

reset_or_keep () {
    echo "Received $1"
}

handle_files() {
    while read filename ; do
        reset_or_keep "$filename"
    done
}

git status --porcelain | sed -e "s/^[ \t]*[A-Z][ \t]*//g" | handle_files
```

(Note that I had to make a small change to your `sed` expression to handle the output format from my `git status`.)

Be aware that, as with `xargs` without the `-0` flag, this program will not work correctly with file names containing whitespace.