# allow user to complete parallel / xargs command (function) after selecting files into array; quoting nuls correctly in printf script

Tags: arrays, bash, parallel-processing, nul, fzf

This is a follow-on question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60330065/calling-shell-function-using-parallel-with-list-of-quoted-filenames-as-input)

In that question, I could get selected files into an array and pass them to a command / function (already exported).  This question differs in that I would like the user to complete the command after selecting  the files.

Main Aim: I am presented with a list of filenames (FZF).  I manually select some of these.  FZF then puts this subset into an array.  I then want to compose an unfinished command which expects the user to complete the command and press `Enter`.

The filenames can have spaces in them; hence the choice of Null-separated.

I'm using `FZF` to select the files.  It produces an array containing nul-ending filenames, I think. But the first item that `FZF` produces is the name of a key-press. That's why the script treats the first item  of `FZF`'s output differently.

Currently I have

```
#!/bin/bash
readarray -d '' out < <(fd .|fzf  --print0 -e -m  --expect=ctrl-e,ctrl-l)
if [ ${#out[@]} -eq 0 ]; then return 0
fi
declare -p out
key="$out"
y=${out[@]:1}
if [ ${#y[@]} -eq 0 ]; then return 0
fi
case "$key" in
ctrl-e ) echo do something ;;
ctrl-l ) echo do something else ;;
* )
printf -v array_str '%q ' "${y[@]}"
cmd="printf '%s\0' ${array_str} | parallel -0 wc"
read -e -i "$cmd" cmd_edited; eval "$cmd_edited" ;; #not working
esac
```

I have gotten close: the command looks like it should, but the NUL values are not behaving.
The last line doesn't work.  It is intended to print the array of files on a line with null separator and still allow the user to specify a function (already exported) before hitting `Enter`.  The `parallel` command would apply the function to each file in the array.

```
$ls
file 1
file 2
...
...
file 100
```

Currently, if I choose `file 3` and `file 2`, the output of my script looks like this:

`printf "%s\0" file 3 file 2 | parallel -0`

to which I might for example, append `wc`

But then after I type `wc` and press `Enter`  I get the following result:

```
printf "%s\0" file 3 file 2 | parallel -0 wc
wc: file030file020: No such file or directory
```

**Edit**: I have now included the line `declare -p out` to make clear what FZF is producing.
The results as they now appear, using Charles' modification below is:

```
declare -a out=([0]="" [1]="file 3" [2]="file 2" [3]="file 1")
printf '%s\0' file\ 3\ file\ 2\ file\ 1  | parallel -0 wc
wc: file030file020file010: No such file or directory
```

So something has obviously gone wrong with the nuls.

How do I fix the code?

Comment: To clear up the "I think", I'd suggest using `declare -p out` to print the definition of the `out` array. That way folks who want to answer this question don't need to look into behavior of the `fd | fzf` pipeline. :)

Comment: BTW, using `eval` is generally not great form. What's the intent behind the decision to do so here?

Comment: The `eval` I thought was mandatory, copied from solution https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213799/can-bash-write-to-its-own-input-stream in section at very bottom of page.

Comment: There, the goal is to parse user-entered data, read by `read`, as shell syntax; it's a legitimate use case. Is that something you're trying to do here? For details on why `eval` is frowned on when used unnecessarily (and why many of the new features bash adds over the baseline POSIX sh specification exist to reduce the number of cases where `eval` is necessary), see [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

Comment: BTW, if that *is* your goal, you should probably be more careful about how you form the initial `cmd` string. `${y[@]}` in a string does not generate a string that evaluates back to the contents of the array `y`.

Comment: Add `-r` to the `read`.

Comment: BTW, you probably don't want an empty `out[0]`. I'd suggest looking into why your `fd | fzf` pipeline is giving you a *leading* NUL, instead of only putting NULs *after* filenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring whether `fzf` and `parallel` do what you want, the following quite certainly doesn't:

```
cmd="printf \"%s\0\" ${y[@]} | parallel -0 wc"
```

Why? Because `${y[@]}` doesn't insert quoting and escaping necessary to make the contents of the `y` array be expressed as valid shell syntax (to refer to the data's original contents when fed back through `eval`).

---

If you want to insert data into a string that's going to be parsed as code, it needs to be escaped first. The shell can do that for you using `printf %q`:

```
printf -v array_str '%q ' "${y[@]}"
cmd="printf '%s\0' ${array_str} | parallel -0 wc"
IFS= read -r -e -i "$cmd" cmd_edited; eval "$cmd_edited"
```

Comment: updated my code to include your changes; but still getting error.

Comment: used updated code, still getting error:
declare -a out=([0]="" [1]="file 3" [2]="file 2" [3]="file 1")
printf '%s\0' file\ 3\ file\ 2\ file\ 1  | parallel -0 wc
wc: 'file 3 file 2 file 1': No such file or directory

Comment: `xargs -0` doesn't work either: `wc: 'file 3 file 2 file 1': No such file or directory`

Comment: does this mean that the obstacle might be the fzf output?  does the `declare` statement reveal nulls or lack thereof?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208526/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-tim).

Comment: earlier error in my code caused problem. `y=${out[@]:1}` should be `y=( "${out[@]:1}" )`. Code works now

Answer (score 2):

It is still unclear to me what you want to do. Comment your code and make sure every variable name has a name that says what it is used for.

Do you want the user to be able to enter a command and have that command run on the files in the array?

```
# Set y
y=("file  1" "file \"two\"")
# What command does the user want to run?
# The command is a GNU Parallel command template
# So {} will be replaced with the argument
IFS= read -r command_to_run
# Run $command_to_run for every @y.
# -0 is needed if an element in @y contains \n
parallel -0 "$command_to_run" ::: "${y[@]}"
```

Or maybe:

```
# Set default command template
cmd='printf "%s\0" "${y[@]}" | parallel -0 wc'
# Let the user edit the template
IFS= read -r -e -i "$cmd"
# Run the input
eval "$REPLY"
```

Comment: I'd suggest making that `IFS= read -r command_to_run`. Without the `-r`, backslashes the user enters will be consumed by the `read` command rather than assigned to the variable. Without clearing IFS, leading and trailing whitespace will be removed.

Comment: (With that fixed, avoiding the use of `eval` altogether certainly makes this the better-practice answer).

Comment: Thanks. Fixed now.

Comment: still getting error: 
declare -a out=([0]="" [1]="file 3" [2]="file 2" [3]="file 1")
printf "%s\0" ${y[@]} | parallel -0 wc
wc: file: No such file or directory
wc: 3: No such file or directory
...

Comment: `${y[@]}`, not `"${y[@]}"`? Quotes matter. I'd suggest switching from double to single quotes for the whole string: `cmd='printf "%s\0" "${y[@]}" | parallel -0 wc'`; that way you avoid the need for internal escaping.

Comment: that leads to
wc: 'file 3 file 2 file 1': No such file or directory

Comment: earlier error in my code caused problem. `y=${out[@]:1}` should be `y=( "${out[@]:1}" )`.  Code works now.