# pipe stdio to a function

Tags: bash, parameters, pipe, xargs

Noob question!

I've got a function on the command line that takes parameters

```
sqr() { echo $(( $1 * $1 )) ; }
```

sqr 4 echos 16. fine.

Now I want to pipe an output to this function

```
echo 4 | sqr
```

I get " syntax error: operand expected (error token is "* ") " - clearly $1 is empty

I've tried using xargs with various options to pass the stdio to the function but I get "No such file or directory" errors. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be using [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) on `$1` to have `cat` flush STDIN as fallback:

```bash
$ sqr() { n=${1:-$(cat)}; echo $((n*n)); }

$ sqr 6
36

$ echo 5 | sqr
25

$ echo 5 | sqr 6  # $1 takes precedence over STDIN
36
```

Comment: Note: this is just an improvement from my previous answer and this is not a solution for the `file not found` error ^^

Comment: @Gilles To my understanding, the actual error was the "syntax error: operand expected" (as `$1` does not provide contents from STDIN, which can be resolved as shown using parameter expansion). The "No such file or directory" error was OP's attempt to mitigate the problem using `xargs`, rendering it an XY problem.

Comment: OOps yes, sorry for the latest 'assertion'

Comment: I love the elegance of this answer, it has taught me loads about parameter expansion. I'm going to try to use my new powers to write a function that can do the same with two parameters. $(cat) doesn't seem to like that, so It's time for some experimentation. Many thanks for a new rabbit hole. lol

Answer (score 1):

The issue with `xargs` is that it use a *subshell*, so your function is not inherited in the new shell.

If you create a new command accessible in `PATH`, then you could use `xargs` and add a feature to be able to use [`STDIN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) or arguments dynamically::

`~/bin/sqr`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $1 ]]; then
    arg=$1
else
    arg=$(cat)
fi
echo $(( $arg * $arg ))
```

```
chmod +x ~/bin/sqr
PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

Now:

```
$ echo 6 | xargs -n1 sqr
36

$ echo 6 | sqr 
36

$ sqr 6
36
```

The part `arg=$(cat)` slurp `STDIN` in the variable `arg`.

Comment: You could mention that exporting the function lets you use it with xargs, as mentionned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003418/calling-shell-functions-with-xargs)

Comment: @Aaron: try it :)

Comment: Nevermind, you do need to xargs bash -c which isn't as elegant as using a script

Answer (score 1):

Parameters and standard input are two fairly different ways for a caller to communicate with a function:

```
sqr_param () {
    local n
    n=$1
    echo $(( $n * $n ))
}

sqr_stdin () {
    local n
    read -r n
    echo $(( $n * $n ))
}
```

Writing them both out in a fairly verbose manner lets you see that one (the "impure") version can be trivially implemented in terms of the other ("pure") version.

```
# This one focuses on math
sqr () {
    echo $(( $1 * $1 ))
}

# This one provides an interface with the outside world
sqr_stdin () {
    local n
    read -r n
    sqr "$n"
}
```

I would resist the urge to try to implement a single function that can handle either an argument or standard input. "So much complexity in software comes from trying to make one thing do two things."

Comment: Disagree. Good software handle both STDIN and arguments

Comment: "Good software" and "single function" are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sqr() {
    local n tmpfd
    exec {tmpfd}<&0             # Save value of FD 0 (stdin) in "tmpfd"
    (( $# )) && exec <<<"$1"    # If an argument passed in create a
                                # temp file, store that value in it,
                                # then set FD 0 to point to that file.
    IFS= read -r n              # Read a value from FD 0
    exec 0<&"$tmpfd"            # Restore FD 0 to the value in "tmpfd"
    echo $(( $n * $n ))         # Print the result of the math
}
```

```
$ sqr 4
16
```

```
$ echo 4 | sqr
16
```

The above uses a named file descriptor `tmpfd`, available in bash 4.1 or later. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/FileDescriptor for more info on file descriptors.

Alternatively, if you define the function body in a subshell then you don't need to save and restore FD 0 since the `exec` directive will only apply within the subshell:

```
$ sqr() {
  (                             # Start a subshell
    local n
    (( $# )) && exec <<<"$1"    # If an argument passed in create a
                                # temp file, store that value in it,
                                # then set FD 0 to point to that file.
    IFS= read -r n              # Read a value from FD 0
    echo $(( $n * $n ))         # Print the result of the math
  )                             # End the subshell
}
```

```
$ sqr 4
16
```

```
$ echo 4 | sqr
16
```

Comment: Looks unnecessary convoluted

Comment: And if you would like to use a subshell, think of `sqr() ( var=$1; echo $(( $var * $var ))  )`

Comment: I know I could just use `(...)` but I'm just not a fan of changing the syntax from `{...}`.