# how do I do the following from a shell script (run several commands at once and wait for them)?

Tags: shell

I want to write a shell scripts that executes a few commands and waits for all of them to terminate.

I think what I would have to do is use

```
      cmd1 &
      cmd2 &
      cmd3 &
      ....
```

etc.

but what I don't know is how to wait for them to terminate.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has the answer to your problem. :)

You would simply `wait` for all running jobs by calling the `wait` command.

[How to wait in bash for several subprocesses to finish and return exit code !=0 when any subprocess ends with code !=0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356100/how-to-wait-in-bash-for-several-subprocesses-to-finish-and-return-exit-code-0)

Comment: ";" wouldn't work for me because I want them to all run together in the background. Kind of like forking and waiting for all the processes you forked to terminate.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `wait` command without any args:

```
cmd1 &
cmd2 &
cmd3 &
wait
```

This will make bash wait for all unfinished children.  This will work as long as you don't have other background tasks that you need to continue as well.

Answer (score 0):

This example seems to work.

```
[stou$ ~]$ (sleep 1 ; echo 1) & (sleep 4 ; echo 4) & (sleep 3 ; echo 3)&  wait; echo done
[1] 13651
[2] 13652
[3] 13653
1
[1]   Done                    ( sleep 1; echo 1 )
3
4
[2]-  Done                    ( sleep 4; echo 4 )
[3]+  Done                    ( sleep 3; echo 3 )
done
[stou$ ~]$
```