# Set variables in parallel in bash

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

Here's an example program:

```
#!/bin/bash

for x in {1..5}
do
  output[$x]=$(echo $x) &
done

wait

for x in {1..5}
do
  echo ${output[$x]}
done
```

I would expect this to run and print out the values assigned to each member of the `output` array, but it prints nothing. Removing the `&` correctly assigns the variables. Must I use different syntax to achieve this in parallel?

Answer (score 4):

This

```
output[$x]=$(echo $x) &
```

puts the *whole* assignment in a background task (sub-process) and that's why you're not seeing the result, since it's not propogated to the parent process.

You can use [wait to wait for subprocesses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356100/how-to-wait-in-bash-for-several-subprocesses-to-finish-and-return-exit-code-0), but returning results (other than status codes) is going to be difficult. Perhaps you can write intermediate results to a file, and collect those results after all processes have finished ? (not nice, I appreciate)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid writing files, you can use `GNU parallel`:

```
#!/bin/bash
output=(`parallel -k --gnu echo {1} ::: {1..5}`)
for i in ${output[@]}
do
   echo $i
done
```

The `-k` is to preserve the order of the output

Answer (score 0):

Use `parset` from GNU Parallel:

```
#!/bin/bash

typeset -A output
parset output echo {} ::: {1..5}

for x in {1..5}
do
  echo ${output[$x]}
done
```