# multiple command prioritization in bash

Tags: bash, process, wait

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to wait in bash for several subprocesses to finish and return exit code !=0 when any subprocess ends with code !=0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356100/how-to-wait-in-bash-for-several-subprocesses-to-finish-and-return-exit-code-0)

I have the following problem:

I have 3 processes that I put in a script

process1
process2
process3

I want that process 1 and 2 run simultaneously but they have both finished before the process 3 starts.

i guess it is something like the following..but I am not sure about that "wait"

```
#!/bin/sh

    (
      process1 &
      process2 &

      wait

      process3

                )
```

Thank you

Fabio

Comment: That will do what you want.  You do not need the (  ) construct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just save the pid of both processes and wait for both to exit

```
#!/bin/bash

process1 &
pid1=$!
process2 &
pid2=$!

wait ${pid1}
echo "Return value of process1: $?"
wait ${pid2}
echo "Return value of process2: $?"

process3
```

Comment: so the single wait does not make any sense in your opinion?

Comment: It works as well. This is just my habit and I think it's better because, if you want, you can check the return value of the processes