# Remove an element from a Bash array

Tags: arrays, bash, variables

I need to remove an element from an array in bash shell.
Generally I'd simply do:

```
array=("${(@)array:#<element to remove>}")
```

Unfortunately the element I want to remove is a variable so I can't use the previous command.
Down here an example:

```
array+=(pluto)
array+=(pippo)
delete=(pluto)
array( ${array[@]/$delete} ) -> but clearly doesn't work because of {}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Which shell? Your example looks like `zsh`.

Comment: `array=( ${array[@]/$delete} )` works as expected in Bash. Have you simply missed the `=`?

Comment: @Ken, that's not quite what's wanted - it will remove any matches from each string, and leave empty strings in the array where it matches the whole string.

Answer (score 291, accepted):

The following works as you would like in `bash` and `zsh`:

```
$ array=(pluto pippo)
$ delete=pluto
$ echo ${array[@]/$delete}
pippo
$ array=( "${array[@]/$delete}" ) #Quotes when working with strings
```

If need to delete more than one element:

```
...
$ delete=(pluto pippo)
for del in ${delete[@]}
do
   array=("${array[@]/$del}") #Quotes when working with strings
done
```

**Caveat**

This technique actually removes prefixes matching `$delete` from the elements, not necessarily whole elements.

**Update**

To really remove an exact item, you need to walk through the array, comparing the target to each element, and using `unset` to delete an exact match.

```
array=(pluto pippo bob)
delete=(pippo)
for target in "${delete[@]}"; do
  for i in "${!array[@]}"; do
    if [[ ${array[i]} = $target ]]; then
      unset 'array[i]'
    fi
  done
done
```

Note that if you do this, and one or more elements is removed, the indices will no longer be a continuous sequence of integers.

```
$ declare -p array
declare -a array=([0]="pluto" [2]="bob")
```

The simple fact is, arrays were not designed for use as mutable data structures. They are primarily used for storing lists of items in a single variable without needing to waste a character as a delimiter (e.g., to store a list of strings which can contain whitespace).

If gaps are a problem, then you need to rebuild the array to fill the gaps:

```
for i in "${!array[@]}"; do
    new_array+=( "${array[i]}" )
done
array=("${new_array[@]}")
unset new_array
```

Comment: just know that: `$ array=(sun sunflower)`
`$ delete=(sun)`
`$ echo ${array[@]/$delete}`
results in `flower`

Comment: Good point. At least in `zsh`, `${array[@]/#%$delete}` works to restrict the match to full words.

Comment: Note that this is actually doing a substitution, so if the array is something like `(pluto1 pluto2 pippo)` then you will end up with `(1 2 pippo)`.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen, I use a for loop to process the case when delete=(pluto pippo). If someone have a better idea, pls give do share

Comment: Just be careful using this in a for loop because you'll end up with an empty element where the deleted element was. For sanity you could do something like
`for element in "${array[@]}"
do
    if [[ $element ]]; then
        echo ${element}
    fi
done`

Comment: So how to delete only matching elements?

Comment: Note: this may set the respective value to nothing, but the element will still be in the array.

Comment: Regarding the caveat: it's removing `$del` wherever it matches, not necessarily just prefixes. Removing prefixes would be `${array[@]/#$del}` (at least in Bash).

Comment: @BenjaminW. I believe just `${array[@]/$del}` will delete anything prefixed. To take a previously quoted example, if `$ array=( sun flowersun )` `$ del=(sun)`, then `${array[@]/$del}` will result in `flowersun`.

Comment: @Izy No, it results in `flower`. For `flowersun`, you'd have to use `${array[@]/#$del}`. Again, not speaking for zsh, just Bash.

Comment: In order to recreate the array, because the gaps have to disappear, the following is sufficient: `arr=("${arr[@]}")`

Comment: At least for associated array you should use `array[$i]` instead of `array[i]` if you mean that the index is the value of variable i, not string 'i'.

Comment: @jarno That's just one problem. Another is that `array=("${new_array[@]}")` won't make a copy of the array.

Comment: Using `[[` introduces a stealth bug as the RHS is treated as a glob. Using `del=('pluto*')` will mess stuff up.

Comment: I tried just the first one. mmm does not work as expected.

Comment: Where did you locate that syntax `${array[@]/$delete}`? It's not in the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html).

Comment: It's not specific to array expansions. It's documented under [Shell Parameter Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Comment: While it's unfortunate that you can't use both anchors at once in the replacement expansion (i.e. this doesn't work: `array=( "${array[@]/#%$delete}" )`, you could just use `printf`,`grep`, & xargs: `array=( $(printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" | grep -vow "${delete[@]/#/-e}" | xargs) )`... Maybe I'll add an additional answer for clarity...

Comment: Ah @Niklas Holm beat me to it

Comment: This is a really bad answer (at least the first technique) as it does not really remove the matching element, but merely replaces it with an empty string. And if you remove the double-quotes, then it will perform word-splitting on the array elements, which is again not what you want. Check yourself with `declare -p array`.

Answer (score 47):

You could build up a new array without the undesired element, then assign it back to the old array. This works in `bash`:

```
array=(pluto pippo)
new_array=()
for value in "${array[@]}"
do
    [[ $value != pluto ]] && new_array+=($value)
done
array=("${new_array[@]}")
unset new_array
```

This yields:

```
echo "${array[@]}"
pippo
```

Answer (score 26):

This is the most direct way to unset a value if you know it's position.

```
$ array=(one two three)
$ echo ${#array[@]}
3
$ unset 'array[1]'
$ echo ${array[@]}
one three
$ echo ${#array[@]}
2
```

Comment: Try `echo ${array[1]}`, you will get null string. And to get `three` you need to do `echo ${array[2]}`. So `unset` is not the right mechanism to remove an element in bash array.

Comment: @rashok, no, `${array[1]+x}` is null string, so `array[1]` is unset. `unset` does not change the indexes of the remaining elements. Quoting the argument for unset is not needed. The way to destroy an array element is described in [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html).

Comment: @rashok I don't see why not. You cannot assume that `${array[1]}` exists just because the size is 2. If you want the indices, check `${!array[@]}`.

Comment: you can update/refresh the index by:
`array=(${array[*]})`

Comment: Quoting the argument for unset _is_ needed if the index is a variable that needs expanding.  (This isn't an array-specific thing, just dealing with order of expansions.)  I realize that's not part of the given example, however; just mentioning it for future readers.

Comment: @FullStackAlex That breaks members that contain shell meta-characters or separators present in `$IFS`. The generic way to reindex a sparse, numerically-indexed array, and preserve the original values, is `array=("${array[@]}")`

Answer (score 10):

**This answer is specific to the case of deleting multiple values from large arrays, where performance is important.**

The most voted solutions are (1) pattern substitution on an array, or (2) iterating over the array elements. The first is fast, but can only deal with elements that have distinct prefix, the second has O(n*k), n=array size, k=elements to remove. Associative array are relative new feature, and might not have been common when the question was originally posted.

For the exact match case, with large n and k, possible to improve performance from O(n*k) to O(n+k*log(k)). In practice, O(n) assuming k much lower than n. Most of the speed up is based on using associative array to identify items to be removed.

Performance (n-array size, k-values to delete). Performance measure seconds of user time

```
   N     K     New(seconds) Current(seconds)  Speedup
 1000   10     0.005        0.033             6X
10000   10     0.070        0.348             5X
10000   20     0.070        0.656             9X
10000    1     0.043        0.050             -7%
```

As expected, the `current` solution is linear to N*K, and the `fast` solution is practically linear to K, with much lower constant. The `fast` solution is slightly slower vs the `current` solution when k=1, due to additional setup.

The 'Fast' solution: array=list of input, delete=list of values to remove.

```
        declare -A delk
        for del in "${delete[@]}" ; do delk[$del]=1 ; done
                # Tag items to remove, based on
        for k in "${!array[@]}" ; do
                [ "${delk[${array[$k]}]-}" ] && unset 'array[k]'
        done
                # Compaction
        array=("${array[@]}")
```

Benchmarked against `current` solution, from the most-voted answer.

```
    for target in "${delete[@]}"; do
        for i in "${!array[@]}"; do
            if [[ ${array[i]} = $target ]]; then
                unset 'array[i]'
            fi
        done
    done
    array=("${array[@]}")
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's a one-line solution with mapfile:

```
$ mapfile -d $'\0' -t arr < <(printf '%s\0' "${arr[@]}" | grep -Pzv "<regexp>")
```

Example:

```
$ arr=("Adam" "Bob" "Claire"$'\n'"Smith" "David" "Eve" "Fred")

$ echo "Size: ${#arr[*]} Contents: ${arr[*]}"

Size: 6 Contents: Adam Bob Claire
Smith David Eve Fred

$ mapfile -d $'\0' -t arr < <(printf '%s\0' "${arr[@]}" | grep -Pzv "^Claire\nSmith$")

$ echo "Size: ${#arr[*]} Contents: ${arr[*]}"

Size: 5 Contents: Adam Bob David Eve Fred
```

This method allows for great flexibility by modifying/exchanging the grep command and doesn't leave any empty strings in the array.

Comment: @Socowi You're incorrect, at least on bash 4.4.19. `-d $'\0'` works perfectly fine while just `-d` without the argument does not.

Comment: Ah yes, I mixed it up. Sorry. What I meant was: `-d $'\0'` is the same as`-d $'\0 something'` or just `-d ''`.

Comment: Doesn't hurt to use `$'\0'` for clarity though

Comment: First `-P` is non-POSIX (and not supported by BSD grep), consider `-E` for EREs instead. Second, while this is in some ways more flexible as is, the following supports the case where you have another array of items to delete as in other answers: `mapfile -d $'\0' -t arr2 < <(printf '%s\0' "${arr[@]}" | grep -Ezvw "${delete[@]/#/-e}")`

Answer (score 5):

## Partial answer only

To delete the first item in the array

```
unset 'array[0]'
```

To delete the last item in the array

```
unset 'array[-1]'
```

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf there is no need to use quotes for the argument of `unset`.

Comment: @jarno: these quotes MUST be used: if you have a file named `array0` in the current directory, then since `array[0]` is glob, it will first be expanded to `array0` before the unset command.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf you are correct. This should be corrected in [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) that currently says "unset name[subscript] destroys the array element at index subscript".

Answer (score 3):

Here's a (probably very bash-specific) little function involving bash variable indirection and `unset`; it's a general solution that does not involve text substitution or discarding empty elements and has no problems with quoting/whitespace etc.

```
delete_ary_elmt() {
  local word=$1      # the element to search for & delete
  local aryref="$2[@]" # a necessary step since '${!$2[@]}' is a syntax error
  local arycopy=("${!aryref}") # create a copy of the input array
  local status=1
  for (( i = ${#arycopy[@]} - 1; i >= 0; i-- )); do # iterate over indices backwards
    elmt=${arycopy[$i]}
    [[ $elmt == $word ]] && unset "$2[$i]" && status=0 # unset matching elmts in orig. ary
  done
  return $status # return 0 if something was deleted; 1 if not
}

array=(a 0 0 b 0 0 0 c 0 d e 0 0 0)
delete_ary_elmt 0 array
for e in "${array[@]}"; do
  echo "$e"
done

# prints "a" "b" "c" "d" in lines
```

Use it like `delete_ary_elmt ELEMENT ARRAYNAME` without any `$` sigil. Switch the `== $word` for `== $word*` for prefix matches; use `${elmt,,} == ${word,,}` for case-insensitive matches; etc., whatever bash `[[` supports.

It works by determining the indices of the input array and iterating over them backwards (so deleting elements doesn't screw up iteration order). To get the indices you need to access the input array by name, which can be done via bash variable indirection `x=1; varname=x; echo ${!varname} # prints "1"`.

You can't access arrays by name like `aryname=a; echo "${$aryname[@]}`, this gives you an error. You can't do `aryname=a; echo "${!aryname[@]}"`, this gives you the indices of the variable `aryname` (although it is not an array). What DOES work is `aryref="a[@]"; echo "${!aryref}"`, which will print the elements of the array `a`, preserving shell-word quoting and whitespace exactly like `echo "${a[@]}"`. But this only works for printing the elements of an array, not for printing its length or indices (`aryref="!a[@]"` or `aryref="#a[@]"` or `"${!!aryref}"` or `"${#!aryref}"`, they all fail).

So I copy the original array by its name via bash indirection and get the indices from the copy. To iterate over the indices in reverse I use a C-style for loop. I could also do it by accessing the indices via `${!arycopy[@]}` and reversing them with `tac`, which is a `cat` that turns around the input line order.

A function solution without variable indirection would probably have to involve `eval`, which may or may not be safe to use in that situation (I can't tell).

Comment: This almost works nicely, however it doesn't redeclare the initial array passed into the function, so while that initial array has its values missing, it also has its indexes messed up.  What this mean is that the next call you make to delete_ary_elmt on the same array will not work (or will remove the wrong things).  For instance, after what you have pasted, try running `delete_ary_elmt "d" array` and then re-printing the array.  You will see that the wrong element gets removed.  Removing the last element will also then never work.

Comment: how do we fix the issue pointed out by Scott? I encountered the issue in succeeding calls to the delete function.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the above answers, the following can be used to remove multiple elements from an array, without partial matching:

```
ARRAY=(one two onetwo three four threefour "one six")
TO_REMOVE=(one four)

TEMP_ARRAY=()
for pkg in "${ARRAY[@]}"; do
    for remove in "${TO_REMOVE[@]}"; do
        KEEP=true
        if [[ ${pkg} == ${remove} ]]; then
            KEEP=false
            break
        fi
    done
    if ${KEEP}; then
        TEMP_ARRAY+=(${pkg})
    fi
done
ARRAY=("${TEMP_ARRAY[@]}")
unset TEMP_ARRAY
```

This will result in an array containing:
(two onetwo three threefour "one six")

Answer (score 2):

**Using `unset`**

To remove an element at particular index, we can use `unset` and then do copy to another array. Only just `unset` is not required in this case. Because `unset` does not remove the element it just sets null string to the particular index in array.

```
declare -a arr=('aa' 'bb' 'cc' 'dd' 'ee')
unset 'arr[1]'
declare -a arr2=()
i=0
for element in "${arr[@]}"
do
    arr2[$i]=$element
    ((++i))
done
echo "${arr[@]}"
echo "1st val is ${arr[1]}, 2nd val is ${arr[2]}"
echo "${arr2[@]}"
echo "1st val is ${arr2[1]}, 2nd val is ${arr2[2]}"
```

Output is

```
aa cc dd ee
1st val is , 2nd val is cc
aa cc dd ee
1st val is cc, 2nd val is dd
```

**Using `:<idx>`**

We can remove some set of elements using `:<idx>` also. For example if we want to remove 1st element we can use `:1` as mentioned below.

```
declare -a arr=('aa' 'bb' 'cc' 'dd' 'ee')
arr2=("${arr[@]:1}")
echo "${arr2[@]}"
echo "1st val is ${arr2[1]}, 2nd val is ${arr2[2]}"
```

Output is

```
bb cc dd ee
1st val is cc, 2nd val is dd
```

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal

> ${PARAMETER#PATTERN} # remove from beginning
>
> ${PARAMETER##PATTERN} # remove from the beginning, greedy match
>
> ${PARAMETER%PATTERN} # remove from the end
>
> ${PARAMETER%%PATTERN} # remove from the end, greedy match

In order to do a full remove element, you have to do an unset command with an if statement.  If you don't care about removing prefixes from other variables or about supporting whitespace in the array, then you can just drop the quotes and forget about for loops.

See example below for a few different ways to clean up an array.

```
options=("foo" "bar" "foo" "foobar" "foo bar" "bars" "bar")

# remove bar from the start of each element
options=("${options[@]/#"bar"}")
# options=("foo" "" "foo" "foobar" "foo bar" "s" "")

# remove the complete string "foo" in a for loop
count=${#options[@]}
for ((i = 0; i < count; i++)); do
   if [ "${options[i]}" = "foo" ] ; then
      unset 'options[i]'
   fi
done
# options=(  ""   "foobar" "foo bar" "s" "")

# remove empty options
# note the count variable can't be recalculated easily on a sparse array
for ((i = 0; i < count; i++)); do
   # echo "Element $i: '${options[i]}'"
   if [ -z "${options[i]}" ] ; then
      unset 'options[i]'
   fi
done
# options=("foobar" "foo bar" "s")

# list them with select
echo "Choose an option:"
PS3='Option? '
select i in "${options[@]}" Quit
 do
    case $i in 
       Quit) break ;;
       *) echo "You selected \"$i\"" ;;
    esac
 done
```

Output

```
Choose an option:
1) foobar
2) foo bar
3) s
4) Quit
Option?
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is also this syntax, e.g. if you want to delete the 2nd element :

```
array=("${array[@]:0:1}" "${array[@]:2}")
```

which is in fact the concatenation of 2 tabs. The first from the index 0 to the index 1 (exclusive) and the 2nd from the index 2 to the end.

Answer (score 0):

If gaps are a problem, then you can make a new array with just 2 lines:

```
arr=(pluto pippo toby)
    unset arr[1]                                   #1ª line
Below are the values, ​​and their indices without continuity:
     for i in "${!arr[@]}"; do
     printf '${arr[%s]}=%s\n' "$i" "${arr[$i]}" >> borramepen;
     done
```

Output: ${arr[0]}=pluto ${arr[2]}=toby

Indices: 0 and 2

```
 To recover the continuity of the indices, it is necessary to do:
    IFS=' ' read -ra arr <<< "$(echo ${arr[@]})"   #2ª line

 Then, the output will be:
    for i in "${!arr[@]}"; do
    printf '${arr[%s]}=%s\n' "$i" "${arr[$i]}"
    done
```

Output: ${AR[0]}=pluto ${AR[1]}=toby

Indices: 0 and 1

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, with the only 2 shortest possible lines, to remove an array element and revive after that.

```
arr=(pluto pippo toby)
```

#check who is offside

```
echo ${arr[@]}
echo ${!arr[*]}
```

#remove the element

```
unset arr[1] (the shortest line 1)
```

#check who is offside

```
echo ${arr[@]}
echo ${!arr[*]}
```

#make a revival (the shortest line 2)

```
arr=(${arr[@]})
```

#check that no one is offside now

```
echo ${arr[@]}
echo ${!arr[*]}
```

Answer (score -1):

In ZSH this is dead easy (note this uses more bash compatible syntax than necessary where possible for ease of understanding):

```
# I always include an edge case to make sure each element
# is not being word split.
start=(one two three 'four 4' five)
work=(${(@)start})

idx=2
val=${work[idx]}

# How to remove a single element easily.
# Also works for associative arrays (at least in zsh)
work[$idx]=()

echo "Array size went down by one: "
[[ $#work -eq $(($#start - 1)) ]] && echo "OK"

echo "Array item "$val" is now gone: "
[[ -z ${work[(r)$val]} ]] && echo OK

echo "Array contents are as expected: "
wanted=("${start[@]:0:1}" "${start[@]:2}")
[[ "${(j.:.)wanted[@]}" == "${(j.:.)work[@]}" ]] && echo "OK"

echo "-- array contents: start --"
print -l -r -- "-- $#start elements" ${(@)start}
echo "-- array contents: work --"
print -l -r -- "-- $#work elements" "${work[@]}"
```

Results:

```
Array size went down by one:
OK
Array item two is now gone:
OK
Array contents are as expected:
OK
-- array contents: start --
-- 5 elements
one
two
three
four 4
five
-- array contents: work --
-- 4 elements
one
three
four 4
five
```

Comment: Sorry, just tried. It did not work in zsh for an assoziative array

Comment: It works just fine, I just tested it (again). Things not working for you? Please explain what did not work exactly in as much detail as you can. What ZSH version are you using?

Answer (score -1):

What I do is:

```
array="$(echo $array | tr ' ' '\n' | sed "/itemtodelete/d")"
```

BAM, that item is removed.

Comment: This breaks for `array=('first item' 'second item')`.

Answer (score -1):

This is a quick-and-dirty solution that will work in simple cases but will break if (a) there are regex special characters in `$delete`, or (b) there are any spaces at all in any items.  Starting with:

```
array+=(pluto)
array+=(pippo)
delete=(pluto)
```

Delete all entries exactly matching `$delete`:

```
array=(`echo $array | fmt -1 | grep -v "^${delete}$" | fmt -999999`)
```

resulting in
`echo $array` -> pippo, and making sure it's an array:
`echo $array[1]` -> pippo

`fmt` is a little obscure: `fmt -1` wraps at the first column (to put each item on its own line.  That's where the problem arises with items in spaces.)  `fmt -999999` unwraps it back to one line, putting back the spaces between items.  There are other ways to do that, such as `xargs`.

Addendum: If you want to delete just the first match, use sed, as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/236700/delete-only-first-hit-match-with-sed):

```
array=(`echo $array | fmt -1 | sed "0,/^${delete}$/{//d;}" | fmt -999999`)
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually, I just noticed that the shell syntax somewhat has a behavior built-in that allows for easy reconstruction of the array when, as posed in the question, an item should be removed.

```bash
# let's set up an array of items to consume:
x=()
for (( i=0; i<10; i++ )); do
    x+=("$i")
done

# here, we consume that array:
while (( ${#x[@]} )); do
    i=$(( $RANDOM % ${#x[@]} ))
    echo "${x[i]} / ${x[@]}"
    x=("${x[@]:0:i}" "${x[@]:i+1}")
done
```

Notice how we constructed the array using bash's `x+=()` syntax?

You could actually add more than one item with that, the content of a whole other array at once.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid conflicts with array index using `unset` - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49626928/3223785 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/47798640/3223785 for more information - reassign the array to itself: `ARRAY_VAR=(${ARRAY_VAR[@]})`.

```
#!/bin/bash

ARRAY_VAR=(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
unset ARRAY_VAR[5]
unset ARRAY_VAR[4]
ARRAY_VAR=(${ARRAY_VAR[@]})
echo ${ARRAY_VAR[@]}
A_LENGTH=${#ARRAY_VAR[*]}
for (( i=0; i<=$(( $A_LENGTH -1 )); i++ )) ; do
    echo ""
    echo "INDEX - $i"
    echo "VALUE - ${ARRAY_VAR[$i]}"
done

exit 0
```

[Ref.: https://tecadmin.net/working-with-array-bash-script/ ]

Answer (score -2):

How about something like:

```
array=(one two three)
array_t=" ${array[@]} "
delete=one
array=(${array_t// $delete / })
unset array_t
```

Answer (score -3):

POSIX shell script does not have arrays.

So most probably you are using a specific dialect such as `bash`, korn shells or `zsh`.

Therefore, your question as of now cannot be answered.

Maybe this works for you:

```
unset array[$delete]
```

Comment: Hi, I'm using bash shell atm. And "$delete" is not the position of the element but the string itself. So I don't think "unset" will work

Answer (score -3):

```
#/bin/bash

echo "# define array with six elements"
arr=(zero one two three 'four 4' five)

echo "# unset by index: 0"
unset -v 'arr[0]'
for i in ${!arr[*]}; do echo "arr[$i]=${arr[$i]}"; done

arr_delete_by_content() { # value to delete
        for i in ${!arr[*]}; do
                [ "${arr[$i]}" = "$1" ] && unset -v 'arr[$i]'
        done
        }

echo "# unset in global variable where value: three"
arr_delete_by_content three
for i in ${!arr[*]}; do echo "arr[$i]=${arr[$i]}"; done

echo "# rearrange indices"
arr=( "${arr[@]}" )
for i in ${!arr[*]}; do echo "arr[$i]=${arr[$i]}"; done

delete_value() { # value arrayelements..., returns array decl.
        local e val=$1; new=(); shift
        for e in "${@}"; do [ "$val" != "$e" ] && new+=("$e"); done
        declare -p new|sed 's,^[^=]*=,,'
        }

echo "# new array without value: two"
declare -a arr="$(delete_value two "${arr[@]}")"
for i in ${!arr[*]}; do echo "arr[$i]=${arr[$i]}"; done

delete_values() { # arraydecl values..., returns array decl. (keeps indices)
        declare -a arr="$1"; local i v; shift
        for v in "${@}"; do 
                for i in ${!arr[*]}; do
                        [ "$v" = "${arr[$i]}" ] && unset -v 'arr[$i]'
                done
        done
        declare -p arr|sed 's,^[^=]*=,,'
        }
echo "# new array without values: one five (keep indices)"
declare -a arr="$(delete_values "$(declare -p arr|sed 's,^[^=]*=,,')" one five)"
for i in ${!arr[*]}; do echo "arr[$i]=${arr[$i]}"; done

# new array without multiple values and rearranged indices is left to the reader
```

Comment: Can you add some comments or a description to tell us about your answer?