# Remove multiple elements from array based on index

Tags: bash

I would like to remove multiple elements from an array based on their indexes.

```
array=("a" "b" "c" "d")
indexes=(1 3)
```

Output should be

```
array=("a" "c")
```

I know how to remove an element from an array knowing the index of the element:

If $i is the index:

```
array=("${(@)array[1,$i-1]}" "${(@)array[$i+1,$#array]}")
```

But what if I have multiple elements to remove? If I loop over the array of indexes, once I have removed one element the other indexes won't correspond anymore to the elements to be removed. So how is it possible to do that?

Comment: Don't know about bash, but in other languages I'd loop backwards.

Comment: The example you show is `zsh`, not `bash`.

Comment: @chepner so I don't really know how to do that in pure bash :) or I've read it's complicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860877/remove-element-from-array-shell

Comment: Are you *trying* to do it in `bash`?

Comment: @chepner yes I am! I saw your edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using BASH arrays you can do this easily:

```
# original array
array=("a" "b" "c" "d")

# indexes array
indexes=(1 3)

# loop through indexes array and delete from element array
for i in "${indexes[@]}"; do
   unset "array[$i]"
done

# check content of original array
declare -p array
```

```
declare -a array=([0]="a" [2]="c")
```

---

As per Chepner's comments below if OP wants an array of contiguous indices then loop through differential array and populate a new array

```
# result array
out=()

# loop through differential array and populate result
for i in "${array[@]}"; do
    out+=("$i")
done

declare -p out
```

```
declare -a out=([0]="a" [1]="c")
```

Comment: You don't actually need an associative array for `indexes`, since the keys are still integers.

Comment: This is definitely the simplest way to handle it; the only question is whether the resulting array should have contiguous indices or not.

Comment: I do need contiguous indices indeed, I didn't even know indices could be non-contiguous. So it's actually a lot of code, I thought there might be an easier way but apparently not

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `indices` is sorted, keep a counter of how many items you have already removed, and subtract that from each index in your loop.

```
count=0
for i in $indices; do
  c=$((i - count))
  array=("${(@)array[1,$c-1]}" "${(@)array[$c+1,$#array]}")
  count=$((count + 1))
done
```

In `bash`, the same approach looks like

```
count=0
for i in "${indices[@]}"; do
  c=$((i - count))
  array=( "${array[@]:0:c-1}" "${array[@]:c+1}" )
  count=$((count + 1))
done
```

Comment: c-1 is going to be negative on the first round if index=0