# Strange behaviour while subtracting 2 string arrays

Tags: arrays, bash

I am subtracting `array1` from `array2`
My 2 arrays are

```
array1=(apps argocd cache core dev-monitoring-busk test-ci-cd)
array2=(apps argocd cache core default kube-system kube-public kube-node-lease monitoring)
```

And the way Im subtracting them is

```
for i in "${array2[@]}"; do
         array1=(${array1[@]//$i})
done

echo ${array1[@]}
```

Now my expected result should be

```
dev-monitoring-busk test-ci-cd
```

But my expected result is

```
dev--busk test-ci-cd
```

Although the subtraction looks good but its also deleting the string `monitoring` from `dev-monitoring-busk`. I dont understand why. Can some point out whats wrong here ?

I know that there are other solutions out there for a diff between 2 arrays like

```
echo ${Array1[@]} ${Array2[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -u
```

But this is more of a diff and not a subtraction. So this does not work for me.

Comment: I would add a debug line before you recalc array1, i.e. echo "#dbg : i=[$i] array1=[$array1[@]]". That way you can see which element is causing the problem. Good luck.

Comment: `${array1[@]//$i}` is a string-based replacement, which is a bad idea for data manipulation.  (e.g. `x=(abc cat); echo ${x[@]//a}` results in `bc ct`).  Try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16861932/3282436) instead.

Comment: `array2` contains the string 'monitoring'; the 'subtraction' code is actually a string replacement (same thing @0x5453 mentions) where the replacement is an empty string; when applied against `array1` this has the effect of stripping 'monitoring'  from 'dev-monitoring-busk' thus leaving you with 'dev--busk'

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a kludge but it works ...

- use `comm` to find those items unique to a (sorted) data set
- use `tr` to convert between spaces (' ' == array element separator) and carriage returns ('\n' ; `comm` works on individual lines)
- `echo "${array1[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort` : convert an array's elements into separate lines and sort
- `comm -23 (sorted data set #1) (sorted data set #2)` : compare sorted data sets and return the rows that only exist in data set #1

Pulling this all together gives us:

```
$ array1=(apps argocd cache core dev-monitoring-busk test-ci-cd)
$ array2=(apps argocd cache core default kube-system kube-public kube-node-lease monitoring)

# find rows that only exist in array1

$ comm -23 <(echo "${array1[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort) <(echo "${array2[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort)
dev-monitoring-busk
test-ci-cd

# same thing but this time replace carriage returns with spaces (ie, pull all items onto a single line of output):

$ comm -23 <(echo "${array1[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort) <(echo "${array2[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort) | tr '\n' ' '
dev-monitoring-busk test-ci-cd
```

NOTEs about `comm`:

```
- takes 2 sorted data sets as input
- generates 3 columns of output:
    - (output column #1) rows only in data set #1
    - (output column #2) rows only in data set #2
    - (output column #3) rows in both data sets #1 and #2
- `comm -xy` ==> discard ouput columns 'x' and 'y'
    - `comm -12` => discard output columns #1 and #2 => only show lines common to both data sets (output column #3)
    - `comm -23' => discard output columns #2 and #3 => only show lines that exist in data set #1 (output column #1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, what you want is not to subtract `array1`
from `array2`, but to subtract `array2` from `array1`.
As others are pointing out, `bash` replacement do not work with arrays.
Instead you can make use of an `associative array` if your bash version >= 4.2.

Please try the following:

```
declare -a array1=(apps argocd cache core dev-monitoring-busk test-ci-cd)
declare -a array2=(apps argocd cache core default kube-system kube-public kube-node-lease monitoring)

declare -A mark
declare -a ans

for e in "${array2[@]}"; do
    mark[$e]=1
done

for e in "${array1[@]}"; do
    [[ ${mark[$e]} ]] || ans+=( "$e" )
done

echo "${ans[@]}"
```

- It first iterate over `array2` and marks its elements by using
  an associative arrray `mark`.
- It then iterates over `array1` and add the element to the `answer`
  if it is not seen in the `mark`.