# How I can delete element from original array by indirect reference to it

Tags: bash, shell

I have three arrays:

```
array1=(8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1)
declare -a array2
declare -a array3
```

And **X** that representing which array I should use for some operation
So, first of all I am finding it like this:

```
nameOfArray=array$X[@]
indirectTempArray=("${!nameOfArray}")
echo ${indirectTempArray[@]}  // returns 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 in case if X == 1
```

So, the question is, how I can delete value from original array which reference I have?

Comment: Do you want to keep the original indices?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a plain string to `unset`:

```
array1=(8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1)
X=1
unset "array$X[1]"
declare -p array1
```

results in the array without the second element (index 1):

```
declare -a array1=([0]="8" [2]="6" [3]="5" [4]="4" [5]="3" [6]="2" [7]="1")
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!)
By the way, how I can add value to array$X?

Comment: @БулатХайруллин `declare "array$X[42]=1337"`

Comment: When I do it like this: 
eval array$X+=${array[-1]}
array$X will have 1
eval array$X+=${array[-2]}
array$X will have 12 instead of 1 2 
eval array$X+=${array[-3]}
array$X will have 123 instead of 1 2 3

Comment: I need to add value to the end of array$X

Comment: `declare "array$X+=(42)"`

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it, I would combine the following two ideas:

- [BashFAQ/06 Evaluating Indirect references](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Evaluating_indirect.2Freference_variables)

  ```
  $ realarray=(...); ref=realarray; index=2
  $ tmp=${ref}[index]
  $ echo "${!tmp}"
  ```
- [Remove an element from a Bash array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860877/remove-an-element-from-a-bash-array)

**delete by key:**

```
$ realarray=( 5 4 3 2 1 "foo bar" ); ref=realarray; key=2
$ tmp=${ref}[@]; tmp=( "${!tmp}" )
$ unset "$ref"'['"$key"']'
$ echo "${realarray[@]}"
5 3 2 1 foo bar
$ echo "${#realarray[@]}"
5
```

**delete by value:**

```
$ realarray=( 5 4 3 2 1 "foo bar" ); ref=realarray; value=2
$ tmp=${ref}[@]; tmp=( "${!tmp}" )
$ eval "$ref=()"
$ for i in "${tmp[@]}"; do [ "$i" != "$value" ] && eval "$ref+=(\"$i\")"; done
$ echo "${realarray[@]}"
5 4 3 1 foo bar
$ echo "${#realarray[@]}"
5
```

This removes the element from the array and solves quoting issues. You could write this a bit different by using a second temporary and a single eval, but the idea is the same.