# How to create array-variable from function argument input -- Remove Array Blanks function

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, reference

After [seeing this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860877/remove-an-element-from-a-bash-array), I decided to put together a function to remove array empty elements in case it saves someone a few seconds.

Is there any way to return (or export) a dynamically named input array-variable as the output of a function?

## Ideally

1. User calls: `removeArrayBlanks "newArrayName" "arrayItem1" "" "arrayItem2"...`
2. The function unsets the old array and creates: `${newArrayName[@]}`, which expands to `"arrayItem1" "arrayItem2"` without any blank items or non-sequential index numbers

Also, does anyone have any optimizations/suggestions to the function? I've included the function below. Thanks!

```
removeArrayBlanks() {
    # Usage: Provide array as input, store output as array. 
    # Example 1: mapfile -t lastArray < <(removeArrayBlanks "hate" "" "empty" "array" "items")
    # Example 2: mapfile -t lastArray < <(removeArrayBlanks "${inputArray[@]}")
    [[ $# -lt 2 ]] && echo "Usage: Provide array as an argument." && exit 1 # Ensure input is array
    tempArray=( "$@" ) # Rebuild array from inputs
    for i in "${!tempArray[@]}"; do
        [[ ! -z "${tempArray[$i]}" ]] && finalArray+=( "${tempArray[$i]}" ) # Add non-empty strings
    done && printf '%s\n' "${finalArray[@]}" && unset tempArray && unset finalArray
}
```

Comment: Unless you declare it local, variables assigned in a function are visible in the main script, so you don't need to return it.

Comment: do you want to remove the 'blanks' from the original array, or create a brand new array with no 'blanks'?

Comment: `! -z` seems odd.

Comment: @Barmar ty, was have a hard time getting the new array to be called `$1` from user input. I couldn't find an easy way to 'update' the input array, without forcing the user to have to call a new array name.

Comment: @markp-fus trying to just remove blanks from input array. And, ideally, not have to rename it or declare a new array.

Comment: @Jetchisel it is kinda like a double negative, i hear ya. Was trying to find the best way possible to take non-empty values and put them into a new , fresh array without non-sequential index numbers or empty items.

Comment: @jmtornetta : I took the liberty to remove the _sh_ tag, since the question is not related to `sh` (after all, _sh_  does not have arrays).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- objective is to remove array elements that contain empty strings (aka `'blanks'`) from current array
- function should be able to work for any array (name) passed to the function
- OP is running, or can upgrade to/above, `bash 4.3+` (needed for `nameref` support)

**NOTE:** to 'remove' an array element just `unset` the array reference (eg, `unset array[index#1]`

One idea using a nameref in the function and the `unset` command:

```
function removeArrayBlanks() {

declare -n localarray="${1}"                                  # define nameref; remains a local array variable

for i in "${!localarray[@]}"                                  # loop through indices
do
    [[ -z "${localarray[${i}]}" ]] && unset localarray[${i}]  # remove entries that contain empty strings
done
}
```

In operation:

```
$ myarray=( a "" 1 "" A )
$ typeset -p myarray
declare -a myarray=([0]="a" [1]="" [2]="1" [3]="" [4]="A")

$ removeArrayBlanks myarray
$ typeset -p myarray
declare -a myarray=([0]="a" [2]="1" [4]="A")

# verify localarray not known by parent
$ typeset -p localarray
-bash: typeset: localarray: not found
```

Comment: Thanks @markp-fuso! I didn't realize that the variable would be updated in the current context/shell from which the function was called. I figured I would have had to 'export' the new array somehow.

Comment: Ahh, I see...I suppose I wasn't wrong? I just didn't realized that this was possible: `declare -n` "Give each name the nameref attribute, making it a name reference to another variable. That other variable is defined by the value of name. All references, assignments, and attribute modifications to name, except those using or changing the -n attribute itself, are performed on the variable referenced by name's value."

Comment: keep in mind a function call is (in essence) a macro call (think `replace '<function-name>' with '<function_body>'`) and not a sub-process call; net result is anything you do in the function is actually applied in the 'parent' process; one exception is if you define a variable as 'local' to the function in which case the 'parent' does not see it; in this case the `nameref' is a 'local' variable that also doubles as a **reference** (and not a copy) of the passed in array name

Comment: I opted to populate the array first and then remove/unset the empty strings; you could still implement your logic ... filter out the empty strings before assiging values to the array ... via a function, but also use a `nameref` to eliminate the overhead of creating/printing/trashing 'temporary' arrays ... your choice

Comment: Yes, adding in the nameref was one thing I didn't realize. The other thing I am seeing that I missed was not expanding out the array as function argument. That is, I was doing `removeArrayBlanks ${inputArray[@]}` which I gather would cause the array name to be lost, because the array is expanded before function can do stuff to it.