# list handling in bash scripts

Tags: bash, list

I would like to do something that is very simple (and with a lot of tutorials) in other languages like python or C, but in bash script.

I would like to work with lists (of strings but could be for anything I suppose)
In concrete I want to

- Create an empty list
- Add an element to the list
- Check if the list is empty
- Erase an element of the list
- Refer to an element of the list by index (to go to "the next")

How can I implement this in bash script?
(If lists are not available, perhaps then arrays?)

Comment: Bash just has arrays, which can be either indexed or associative. They can just contain strings, there are no higher level structures in bash.

Comment: Read about them in the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#Arrays)

Comment: I have managed to resolve almost all of what I asked. The only thing I still don't know is how to remove an element of the array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860877/remove-an-element-from-a-bash-array

Comment: `unset` is how to do that.

Comment: You could use a **Redis** list then your array would be accessible across your entire network, e.g. `redis-cli lpush array value` stores a value in a list and `redis-cli lset array 3 "hello"` changes entry 3 to "hello".

Answer (score 0):

Before my question is closed ... I put here some answers

-Create an empty list

`arr=()`

-Add an element to the list

~~Not sure about this. I thought it was
arr=($newvalue "$arr[@]")   but it is not.~~

```
arr=( $newvalue "${arr[@]}")
```

- Check if the list is empty

```
if ((${#arr[@]})); then   #the number is not 0
  echo "array is not empty"
else
  echo  "array is empty"
fi
```

- Erase an element of the list
  OPEN QUESTION
- Refer to an element of the list by index (to go to "the next")

```
echo ${arr[0]}
```

I think it is very important to put all these in a question and not going all around the internet to find the answers so here it goes

```
#create an empty array
arr=()
#arr=("eee")
echo "empty array"
echo ${arr[@]}
newvalue=000

#add new element
echo "add elements"

arr=("new_element" "${arr[@]}")
echo ${arr[@]}

arr=( $newvalue "${arr[@]}")
echo ${arr[@]}

echo "first element and number of elements"
echo ${arr[0]}   #refer to an element by index 
echo ${#arr[@]}  #number

echo "is it empty"
if ((${#arr[@]})); then   #the number is not 0
  echo "array is not empty"
else
  echo  "array is empty"
fi

echo "delete element"
arr=("${arr[@]/$newvalue}" )
echo ${arr[@]}
```

Comment: Add element to end of array with `arr+=("new element")`