# BASH: deleting Nth element in an array without another variable

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I'm currently learning shell scripting and I was trying to delete an element during iterations for finding max element in an array. This is just an example:

```
declare -a array=(1 2 3 4)
x=2     #Can I do it without making another variable?
array=( "${array[@]/$x}" )  
echo ${array[@]}
```

This works fine for me but I wonder if there's anyway do this without `x=2`, since `array=( "${array[@]/$2}" )` doesn't work. Thank you.

Comment: `unset array[2]`

Comment: Wow..such an easy way

Comment: `unset array[2]` does not always work.  `unset 'array[2]'` always works.  For a variable index use `unset "array[$x]"`.  See [Bash Pitfalls #57 (unset unquoted array element)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#unset_a.5B0.5D).

Comment: @ChoiChangWoo `array=( "${array[@]/$x}" )` does **not** work for you. It only **apparently** works. Carefully read the excellent answer below and you'll understand why.

Answer (score 1):

To delete an array element by number use `unset`.  Examples:

1. `unset 'array[2]'`
2. `unset "array[$n]"`
3. `unset 'array[n]'`

The quotes are essential in all cases.  See [Bash Pitfalls #57 (unset unquoted array element)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#unset_a.5B0.5D).

Examples 2 and 3 have exactly the same effect (assuming that the value of variable `n` is a valid array index).  Example 3 works because Bash doesn't require a preceding `$` to expand variables in contexts that support arithmetic, including array indexes.

Note that using `unset` on an array index does not change other array indexes.  It produces an array with holes in it (aka a sparse array).  See [Arrays [Bash Hackers Wiki]](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays) for more information.

`echo ${array[@]}` is broken in several ways.  Use [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to find problems like this.  `echo "${array[@]}"` is better (and accepted by Shellcheck) but still broken.  One way that it can fail is if the first element of the array is a valid `echo` option (`-n`, `-e`, or `-E`).

To see exactly what is in array (revealing holes if there are any) use:

```
declare -p array
```

For example

```
array=(a b c d)
declare -p array
n=2
unset 'array[n]'
declare -p array
```

outputs

```
declare -a array=([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="c" [3]="d")
declare -a array=([0]="a" [1]="b" [3]="d")
```

(note the missing index 2 in the second output line).

Beware that `array=( "${array[@]/$x}" )` does *not* delete any array element.  *It just removes the first occurrence of the string in `$x` from each element in the array.*

For example

```
array=(12321 32123)
declare -p array
x=2
array=( "${array[@]/$x}" )
declare -p array
```

outputs

```
declare -a array=([0]="12321" [1]="32123")
declare -a array=([0]="1321" [1]="3123")
```

The example in the question

```
declare -a array=(1 2 3 4)
x=2
array=( "${array[@]/$x}" )
declare -p array
```

outputs

```
declare -a array=([0]="1" [1]="" [2]="3" [3]="4")
```

The second array element (index 1) has not been removed.  It's just been set to the empty string.

There's some useful information in [Remove an element from a Bash array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16860877/4154375).  However, the question is about deleting array elements with particular values, not deleting elements by index.  Also, a lot of the answers (including the accepted (and much-upvoted) one) have serious problems.  Many of the problems are identified in comments, but some of the comments are also very wrong.  Be careful.