# getting all elements of a bash array except a given index

Tags: arrays, bash

Team, I have a use case to save remainder of array into new array while looping on its indices and new array should have all elements except the looped element.

```
$ a=(1 2 3 4 5)
$ b=()

for index in ${!a[@]}
do
 b=(a - a[$index]) #how would i code his that it works ?
 echo ${b[@]}
done
```

expected loop values for each iteration.

```
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 5
1 2 4 5
1 3 4 5
2 3 4 5
```

Comment: See [BASH: deleting Nth element in an array without another variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71154323/4154375).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just be simple.

```
b=("${a[@]}")
unset b[$index]
```

Comment: See [Bash Pitfalls #57 (unset unquoted array element)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#unset_a.5B0.5D).

Answer (score 0):

Use the parameter expansion with the :offset:length syntax:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
a=(1 2 3 4 5)
b=()

for index in "${!a[@]}" ; do
    b=("${a[@]:0:index}")

    # This should be "${a[@]:index+1:${#a[@]}-index-1}",
    # but the result is the same.
    b+=("${a[@]:index+1:${#a[@]}}")

    echo "${b[@]}"
done
```