# unix - how to use wait for multiple background processes

Tags: unix, scripting, ksh

I'm using a korn shell. Is this a possible scenario using wait? Where I have (2) instances of it?

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
a &
wait
b &
c &
wait
d
```

My goal is to run a first, once complete, then fire off b,c at the same time. Once b,c is complete, then run "d".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the semantics of your situation.
It seems to me that the problem that you are facing revolves around waiting for ***both*** b and c.

Here is how this can be solved (potentially)
First you wait on a..the moment the wait returns, you fire b and c. You can use two waits - one for b and one for c..the order of these does not matter since you want to wait on both anyway.
Once both waits have returned, you can fire d.

- Fire a
- Wait a
- Fire b,c

  - Fire b
  - Fire c
- Wait b,c

  - Wait b
  - Wait c
- Fire d

Comment: It depends on whether you want A to run in the background or not..that is entirely up to you. As for B and C, since you want them to run in parallel, you will have to run these in the background. The order of the waits doesn't matter in this case since you want both to complete before executing your next statement

Comment: Is there an additional way to check for b,c to complete before moving on to fire d?

Comment: do you mean simultaneously check? I don't think so..Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/356154/1761555 for some additional details

Comment: you could obtain the PID's of b and c and check whether they've quit (or are still running)

Comment: Could you please mark this as correct if it worked for you? Others might find it useful as well.