# how do i submit multiple jobs with nohup?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have several jobs which i would like to submit in a certain order.
First, multiple jobs like `cal1st_1.sh` `cal1st_2.sh` ... `cal1st_10.sh` are submitted at one time and processed simultaneously. After all of them are finished, i have a job called `post_process.sh`. Then, multiple jobs like `cal2nd_1.sh`, `cal2nd_2.sh` .... `cal2nd_10.sh`, then `post_process.sh` again, I need to do this for four times.

I tried to write a script get_final.sh like

```
#!/bin/bash
./cal1st_1.sh & ./cal1st_2.sh & ./cal1st_3.sh...... & ./cal1st_10.sh
./post_process.sh
./cal2nd_1.sh & ./cal2nd_2.sh & ./cal2nd_3.sh...... & ./cal2nd_10.sh
./post_process.sh
```

and run it with command: `nohup ./get_final.sh &`, but it seems doesn't work, sometimes `post_process.sh` started even `cal1st*sh` weren't all finished, sometimes `cal1st*sh` weren't processed simultaneously. Can someone tell me which part of my codes is wrong? If you have any questions related to my codes, please leave a comment.

**EDIT**

I wrote a script get_final.sh like this, do you think it will work? Should i just execute it with `nohup ./get_final.sh &`

```
#!/bin/bash
pre_cal.sh
for i in `seq 1 13`; do
cal_dis_vel_strain_$i.sh &
done
wait  
echo 1 > record
./post_cal.sh

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone tell me which part of my codes is wrong?

That is wrong is your assumption that the "post-process" tasks won't be started until the previous "cal" processes have finished.  That's not the way that `&` works.  What `&` does is to leave the child process to run in the background ... without waiting for it to finish.

The way to do what you are trying to do is to use the builtin `wait` command, as described here:

- [How to wait in bash for several subprocesses to finish and return exit code !=0 when any subprocess ends with code !=0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356100/how-to-wait-in-bash-for-several-subprocesses-to-finish-and-return-exit-code-0)
- http://www.unixcl.com/2008/06/bash-wait-command.html

In this case, you will need to `wait` for each of the backgrounded processes (in any order).

(The problem is nothing to do with `nohup`.)

---

In response to your followup:

1. That's not correct.  You need to `wait` for each and every child process.  A single `wait` will just wait for one process.
2. Once you've fixed that problem, you can call it like that.  But you only need to do that if there is a possibility that your session will be disconnected before the script finishes.  Another alternative is the `screen` program ... which allows you to detach and reattach the session.

Comment: can you please take a look if my script will work? Thank you. @Stephen C