# check status of multiple rsync running in background

Tags: bash, shell

In my bash shell script, I wanted to fetch data in parallel from remote machines so I used a `&` in between the commands

Since my path was configured at runtime I first used a variable (String by default ) as such,

```
variable1="rsync -a /path/to/${runtime_parameter}_01/abc/xyz.txt"
variable2="rsync -a /path/to/${runtime_parameter}_02/def/ghi.txt"
variable3="rsync -a /path/to/${runtime_parameter}_02/mno/jkl.txt"
```

Then I execute them as follows,

```
`$variable1` & `$variable2` & `$variable3`
```

When using a single `rsync` I make a check verifying if  `$?` i.e. exit status is equal to `0` for success.

My script should not proceed unless the `rsync` process is complete. How do I verify if the process are completed?

Comment: What you've written won't do what you think.  You should be using: `$variable1 & $variable2 & $variable3 &` (with dollar signs prefixing the variable names, no back-ticks, and with an `&` after the third command.  Then your main shell can use `wait`. If you need process IDs, you need: `$variable1 & p1=$! ; $variable2 & p2=$! ; $variable3 & p3=$!` or something equivalent (and the spaces after the `$!` are necessary because otherwise, `bash` says "`!: event not found`" — if I wanted a `csh`, I know how to get one and I dislike `bash` importing `csh`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for other corrections

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You invoke `wait` after spawning all jobs in the background (even the last one).  It will wait until they're all finished.

If you want to get the return status code from each individual child process, take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/356154/4323 (basically, use `wait`, but one PID at a time).

Comment: I'm not sure you need the backticks around `$cmd1` and so on.  Try without.