# How do you script ssh commands then background the session?

Tags: ssh

I am trying to create a single script that starts an ssh session, and execute commands on the remote machine, then backgrounds the session.  So far I've been playing with the -f or -f -N options, but I don't know how to bring the session back to the foreground to verify my commands executed correctly.

Or is there a way that a single script can start the ssh session and continue inputting commands to that newly opened session? and then background that session?
If none of those work I was thinking another way of doing this is a script that starts an ssh session, upload and execute the commands via another script.

any ideas on how to do this.

Comment: More information about exactly what you are trying to accomplish would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you are trying to do. I'll try to be helpful.

A series of commands can be issued sequentially in a single ssh session using a single quoted string with commands separated by semicolons.

```
$ ssh user@remotehost 'ls; echo  foo > bar; cat bar; rm bar'
```

It will return the result of the last command run.

I'm confused about why you want to background the session.

If you need You can start a long running process on the remote machine with nohup and then close the session.

If you just need a series of commands run that each depend on the result of the last one, you don't need to background the process, just put that logic into your command sequence.

```
$ ssh user@remotehost 'if ![ -f bar ];then echo  foo > bar && cat bar && rm bar; fi'
```

No harm in multiple sequential ssh and scp connections if there are a lot of things to be done.

Comment: My idea behind backgrounding the ssh session is so that after the remote commands are executed the session will stay open and the script can go back to executing commands locally.

Comment: I'd suggest you get it working sequentially first, then try backgrounding. But my experience is adding parallelism is often more trouble than it is worth. You will need a different method to verify the results if you background, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356100/how-to-wait-in-bash-for-several-subprocesses-to-finish-and-return-exit-code-0