# run commands in parallel with exit fail if any command fails

Tags: parallel-processing

Need help in a bash script.
The goal is:
- Run several commands in parallel
- Exit 1 if any command return not-zero exit status

I.e.

Run with middle command has error:

```
$ ./parallel_commands "echo 1" "_echo 2" "echo 3" && echo "OK"
1
3
./parallel_commands: line 4: _echo: command not found
OK <- Incorrect
```

Run with all commands have errors:

```
$ ./parallel_commands "_echo 1" "_echo 2" "_echo 3" && echo "OK"
./parallel_commands: line 4: _echo: command not found
./parallel_commands: line 4: _echo: command not found
./parallel_commands: line 4: _echo: command not found
-> Result is fail -> Correct
```

Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for cmd in "$@"; do {
  $cmd & pid=$!
  PID_LIST+=" $pid";
} done

trap "kill $PID_LIST" SIGINT

wait $PID_LIST
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356100/how-to-wait-in-bash-for-several-subprocesses-to-finish-and-return-exit-code-0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like this using GNU Parallel:

```
parallel ::: "echo 1" "_echo 2" "echo 3" && echo OK
```

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel

Comment: Perfect! That is exact what I need. Thanks.