# Run command in parallel and fail the run if any command fails using wait

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, wait, gnu-parallel

I can see there is parallel command which can do similar to what I want and answer is here: [run commands in parallel with exit fail if any command fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050612/run-commands-in-parallel-with-exit-fail-if-any-command-fails)

But I am using very minimal vm image and so I can't use `parallel` .

So Is that possible to run commands in parallel and return exist status fail if any of the command fails in the batch.

Ex.

```
(npm install --global bower ng-cli) & (cd $1 npm install) & (cd $2 bower install); wait
```

In the above command if 2nd command fails, it should return exit status fail.

Please let me know if I should provide any more information.

(Worst case) if someone can help me converting above command to parallel command that will be also useful.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you cannot install GNU Parallel? Is the reason covered on https://oletange.wordpress.com/2018/03/28/excuses-for-not-installing-gnu-parallel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU Parallel:

```
parallel --halt now,fail=1 ::: \
  "npm install --global bower ng-cli" \
  "cd $1 npm install" \
  "cd $2 bower install" && echo All is OK
```

It will return with failure as soon as one of the jobs fail.

Comment: You do not have that in your question, and if that really works, then this will too.

Comment: Yes right, that works but I am getting this warning: 
`Value "now,fail=1" invalid for option halt (number expected)`

though command runs well) I am trying to find help for this. Let me know if u know this already?

Comment: `--halt now,fail=1` is available from version parallel-20140722. From version parallel-20120822 you can use '--halt 2' instead.