# Run while loop until background process finish its job

Tags: linux, shell

In linux shell script i have

```
vlc /some/file/path.mkv &
wait
```

Now until my background process return `wait` call will be blocked. But here i want that until my background process return i want to execute one loop and in that print some data continuous. So when ever my background process return/exit i need to break that loop.

How to do that in shell script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to wait in bash for several subprocesses to finish and return exit code !=0 when any subprocess ends with code !=0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356100/how-to-wait-in-bash-for-several-subprocesses-to-finish-and-return-exit-code-0)

Comment: @realspirituals Sir it looks like my question and its different

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See if this works for you

```
vlc /some/file/path.mkv &
while [[ -n $(jobs -r) ]]; do echo -n "some data"; sleep 1; done
```

`jobs -r` checks running processes, and printing something, the script stops when your vlc process is done.

Comment: Worked like a charm... :)

Comment: I try your idea using `sleep 10 & while [[ -n $(jobs -r) ]]; do echo -n "some data"; sleep 1; done` but busybox (Buildroot) says `some data-sh: jobs: illegal option -r`