# How to run multiple shell script which does not give prompt at the end

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I want to run three processes which all will stop showing that the service is started and prompt will not be given. I want to automate this procedure. I tried using "&" at the end but it pops in the terminal. I tried using "sh +x script1.sh & sh +x script2.sh" [I need to stop the process by pressing ctrl+c for another script to run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHf62.png) Please help in this

Comment: You question is exceedingly terse. You can't abort a program using Ctrl C unless it is running in the foreground.

Comment: check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356100/how-to-wait-in-bash-for-several-subprocesses-to-finish-and-return-exit-code-0), may be can help you

Comment: @sjsam: You can't do it directly, but one could set up a signal handler in the foreground process, which catches the control-c, and then send the corresponding signal to the background process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a general script that launches the three processes in background and waits for the user the press Control+C. Then you add a trap to the general script to launch a shutdown hook.

I think that the solution may look as this:

```
#!/bin/bash

end_processes() {
  echo "Shutdown hook"
  if [ -n $PID1 ]; then
    echo "Killing PID 1 = $PID1"
    kill -9 $PID1
  fi
  if [ -n $PID2 ]; then
    echo "Killing PID 2 = $PID2" 
    kill -9 $PID2
  fi
  if [ -n $PID2 ]; then                                                                                                                                                                 
    echo "Killing PID 3 = $PID3" 
    kill -9 $PID3
  fi
}

# Main code: Add trap
trap end_processes EXIT

# Main code: Launch scripts
./script1.sh &
PID1=$!

./script2.sh &
PID2=$!

./script3.sh &
PID3=$!

# Main code: wait for user to press Control+C
while [ 1 ]; do
  sleep 1s
done
```

Notice that:

- I have added some echo messages just to test.
- Trap executes a function when EXIT is received on the script. You can change the received signal by capturing only a specific signal (i.e. SIGINT)
- The trap function is now killing the processes with -9. I you wish, you can send other kill signals
- The $! retrieves the PID of the most recent backgroud command.
- You can modify the wait loop (the last while command) to sleep firstly for the aproximate time of the processes to finish and then to wait for a more smaller time:

  ```
  APROX_TIME=30s
  POLL_TIME=2s
  sleep $APROX_TIME
  while [ 1 ]; do
    sleep $POLL_TIME
  done
  ```

Comment: @Shreyas please consider [accepting this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it was usefull.