# Shutdown computer when all instances of a given program have finished

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I use the following script to check whether `wget` has finished downloading. To check for this, I'm looking for its PID, and when it is not found the computer shutdowns. This works fine for a single instance of `wget`, however, I'd like the script to look for all already running wget programs.

```
#!/bin/bash

while kill -0 $(pidof wget) 2> /dev/null; do
for i in '-' '/' '|' '\'
do
    echo -ne "\b$i"
    sleep 0.1
done
done
poweroff
```

**EDIT**: I'd would be great if the script would check if at least one instance of `wget` is running and only then check whether `wget` has finished and shutdown the computer.

Comment: Where you getting the pid from? Also you are using a literal string instead of a variable

Comment: @Inian Please have a look at my updated post.

Comment: You can use an array and check that there is at least 1 pid before entering the loop, e.g. `pids=($(pidof wget)); if ((${#pids[@]} > 0)); then # do your loop; fi`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks, it works! Please feel free to provide an answer for my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the other answers, you can satisfy your check for at least one `wget` pid by initially reading the result of `pidof wget` into an array, for example:

```
pids=($(pidof wget))
if ((${#pids[@]} > 0)); then 
    # do your loop
fi
```

This also brings up a way to routinely monitor the remaining pids as each `wget` operation completes, for example,

**edit**

```
npids=${#pids[@]}                           ## save original number of pids
while (( ${#pids[@]} -gt 0 )); do           ## while pids remain
    for ((i = 0; i < npids; i++)); do       ## loop, checking remaining pids
        kill -0 ${pids[i]} || pids[$i]=     ## if not unset in array
    done
    ## do your sleep and spin
done
poweroff
```

There are probably many more ways to do it. This is just one that came to mind.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think kill is a right Idea,

may be some thing on the lines like this

```
while [ 1 ] 
do
     live_wgets=0

     for pid in `ps -ef | grep wget| awk '{print $2}'` ;  # Adjust the grep
     do 
        live_wgets=$((live_wgets+1))
     done

     if test $live_wgets -eq 0; then # shutdown
         sudo poweroff; # or whatever that suits
     fi
     sleep 5; # wait for sometime 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt your script in the following way:

```
#!/bin/bash

spin[0]="-"
spin[1]="\\"
spin[2]="|"
spin[3]="/"

DOWNLOAD=`ps -ef | grep wget | grep -v grep`
while [ -n "$DOWNLOAD" ]; do
for i in "${spin[@]}"
do
    DOWNLOAD=`ps -ef | grep wget | grep -v grep`
    echo -ne "\b$i"
    sleep 0.1
done
done
sudo poweroff
```

However I would recommend using **cron** instead of an **active waiting** approach or even use `wait`

[How to wait in bash for several subprocesses to finish and return exit code !=0 when any subprocess ends with code !=0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356100/how-to-wait-in-bash-for-several-subprocesses-to-finish-and-return-exit-code-0)