# Bash set -e doesn't work as expected(I understand)

Tags: bash

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -exuo pipefail

# Run delorean to update the namespaces folder

main() {
  if [ !$(yq -r '.random' file_that_doesnt_exist.yaml) = "true" ]; then
   echo "yes"
  else
   echo "no"
  fi
}

# shellcheck disable=SC2068
main $@
```

`set -e pipefail` based on my understanding should exit the bash script on the first occurence of error. However, I get "no" in stdout even though `echo "no" occurs after the error. How does that happen?

Comment: You're probably looking for `set -o pipefail` ...

Comment: even with -o i get "no"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set -e` stops the script on error, but not always:

> The shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of the command list immediately following a `while` or `until` keyword, part of the test following the `if` or `elif` reserved words, part of any command executed in a `&&` or `||` list except the command following the final `&&` or  `||`,  any  command  in  a pipeline  but  the  last, or if the command's return value is being inverted with `!`.

(Quote from `man bash`).

Comment: thank you, could you please point me from where could I have known this info? I will skim through these for reference

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622198/what-does-set-e-mean-in-a-bash-script

Comment: was hoping for a man page or a doc

Comment: @Surya, Try `PAGER='less +/\ *-e\ *Exit' man bash`

Comment: @Surya: Check the update. It comes from `man bash`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, don't use `-e` (or at least don't *only* use that.)
Use a `trap`, and carefully design your tests with it in mind.

c.f. this [whole page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50296873/8656552) for good discussions on alternatives and explanations, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55042320/handle-exceptions-in-bash-scripts/55047096#55047096) for some other examples and elaborations that should give you good inspiration for a better solution.