# Bash: throws error for a pid of a background process

Tags: bash

so I have these functions, a part of a larger bash script. And the issue is that my `wait` step is throwing error

> pid 1 is not a child of this shell

```
function getJobId(){
  local result=$(echo "$1" | sed s/^[^0-9]*// | sed s/[^0-9].*$//)
  echo $result
}

function deploy(){
  echo "Building now"
  nohup docker-compose build $1 &> logs/$2.txt &
  lastJob=$(getJobId $(jobs %%))
  echo "lastjob is --- $lastJob"
  jobsList="$jobsList $lastJob"
}

for job in $jobsList
do
  wait $job
  exit_code=$?
  if [[ "$exit_code" != 0 ]]; then
    handleError
  fi
done
```

I checked the `lastJob`, and it contains a valid value. The bash script is executed as root from the terminal of a GCP ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 0):

`wait` expects a `pid`, not a `job id`. The simplest(shortest?) alteration of your
code (untested) seems to be:

```
function deploy(){
  echo "Building now"
  nohup docker-compose build $1 &> logs/$2.txt &
  # lastJob=$(getJobId $(jobs %%))
  # as you are exactly creating a new process here, you
  # already have the new spawned pid in the $! variable:
  lastJob=$! 
  echo "lastjob is --- $lastJob"
  jobsList="$jobsList $lastJob"
}
```

An interesting reference could be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356100/how-to-wait-in-bash-for-several-subprocesses-to-finish-and-return-exit-code-0) stack overflow question.