# Solved, To wait the end of several processes launched from a loop before to increment variables is not working in Bash

Tags: bash

I made a loop in my bash script.

I made a loop where an important thing is it must wait the end of some processe**s**(here scrapy spiders) to be done before to increment variables, which are essential as conditions.

The general algorithm is the following (no programming language used here):

```
#initialisation
count=0
urlsFileNbLines=$( wc -l < urlsFileToScrape )
while count =<5 or urlsFileNbLines != 0
    launch scrapy spiders
    wait scrapy spiders are done
         add 1 (loop) to $count
         update $urlsFileNbLines
```

So, the problem is if I don't use the condition to wait the processes to be done (`until scrapy spiders are done`) , and in the same time I increment the variables, it will launch again scrapy spiders while I must wait the previous are done to update `$urlsFileNbLines`.

---

Now, I gonna tackle the bash language part.

To make this condition: `until scrapy spiders are done`, I was inspired by [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-check-if-process-is-running-or-notonlinuxunix/).
What I understand in **Bash shell script to check running process** part, is if  `pgrep -x scrapy` returns something, then this is `true`, implicitly. So I tried to make a condition where it has to wait until it's `false`.
That's why I tried to make `until [ ! pgrep -x scrapy ]; do ...` and even `until [ ! $(pgrep -x scrapy) ]; do` but it always give errors.

I tried this too:

At `launch scrapy spiders`, there is:

```
for i in `seq 1 5`; do
    scrapy crawl spider -a param=$i & PID$i=$! &
done
echo "here it must wait the end of process. Count value is ${count}"
```

At `until scrapy spiders are done` (just below the previous), there is:

```
for in in `seq 1 5`; do
    wait $PID$i
done
count=$(($count+1))
...
```

But it does not wait, it makes incrementation of `$count` very quickly and goes over 5 because the loop `for i in seq $1 $maxSeq` is not finished that it continues to increment, while the part `& PID$i=$! &` returns issue `script.sh: line 93: PID1=4758 : command not found`. That's messy.

What can I do ?

---

## UPDATE

Thanks to @Barmar I made this solution. And to wait all processes I inspired from this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/356154/10314460).

```
pid=() #an empty array for the pids that are coming
for i in `seq 1 5`; do
    scrapy crawl spider -a param=$i ; pid[$i]=$! &
done
echo "command pgrep before wait" 
echo $(pgrep -x scrapy) 
for pid in ${pid[*]}; do
    wait $pid & echo 'fin du processus ${pid}' &
done
echo "command pgrep after wait"
echo $(pgrep -x scrapy)
```

It is not waiting for the whole processes to be done before to increment variables. Then it launches again same instances of spiders and it creates conflicts of connection.

To write: `wait "${pids[@]}"` instead of the loop works perfectly in my case.

---

bash version: 4.4.20 | OS version: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

Comment: Did you check the return of `wait`?

Comment: You can't combine variables like `$PID$i`. Use an array.

Comment: If you just use `wait` with no arguments it will wait for all background processes to complete, so you don't need the loop.

Comment: @Barmar Why I cannot? It clearly instantiated it well: `PID1=4758`, `PID2=6695` and so on. So I can make `$PID$i=$!`.

Comment: Because it doesn't combine variables that way. `$PID$i` means to get the value of `$PID` and the value of `$i` and concatenate them, it doesn't mean to append `$i` to the variable name and look up `$PID1`, `$PID2`, etc.

Comment: If you want to calculate a variable name dynamically, you need to use `${!PID$i}`.

Comment: And to assign to a calculated variable, you have to use `eval`: `eval "PID$i=$!"`

Comment: It's much easier to use an array: `PID[$i]=$!` and `${PID[$i]}`

Comment: @Barmar ${!PID$i} or not will be the same. I need different PID for each spider of the loop, so $i is essential. Then I gonna try array, even if it need reflexion for the `wait` loop.

Comment: The message `PID1=4758 : command not found` is because you can't instantiate it.

Comment: `man bash` then `/nameref` is also an option.

Comment: @Barmar well, thank you a lot. I made an update on my topic. Your solution works to instantiate PIDs because I have not any trouble with errors now.

Comment: @l0b0 read more next time. This is not a duplicate at all, and not to the topic you tied it.

Comment: I replaced the duplicate link with a more appropriate one. The use of a `pids` array, as shown in the accepted answer there (and in Barmar's comment above), is *exactly* what you should be doing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes it is.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I still have troubles as I said in UPDATES. I replaced by `for pid in "${pids[@]}"` as you said in the tied topic, but I don't know why following instructions are made even if processes are not done.

Comment: You can't put a `&` after the `wait`; to be useful, it **must** be a foreground process.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I replaced the loop of `${pid[*]}` by simply `wait "${pids[@]}"` and it works perfectly as expected now.

Comment: You lose information when you do that; wait one-at-a-time and you get individual exit status for each.