# How to know the gradle process has ended?

Tags: java, shell, gradle, process, automation

I want to get the gradle running process where I can come to know that gradle task has ended.
I am executing gradle tasks parallel in my machines like following.

in Windows,

> ```
> start gradlew runSuite1 -i --rerun-tasks
> start gradlew runSuite1 -i --rerun-tasks
> ```

in Mac,

> ```
>  ./gradlew runSuite1 -i --rerun-tasks &
>  ./gradlew runSuite2 -i --rerun-tasks &
> ```

It will trigger all gradle operations in parallel.

I want to perform one operation once all this gradle tasks are ended.

How to know these gradle running process using java or anything ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use command `wait` in Bash:

```
./gradlew runSuite1 -i --rerun-tasks &
pids[0]=$!

./gradlew runSuite2 -i --rerun-tasks &
pids[1]=$!

for pid in ${pids[*]}; do
    wait $pid
done
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/356154/2158271) for more information.

Comment: is there a way to do it in batch file, I tried it but it is very complicated and couldn't find any solutions. It's not working like shell script.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend relying on the support for [parallelism inside Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:parallel_execution) itself. It would make your experience much easier.

Unless `runSuite1` and `runSuite2` are in the same project, recent Gradle version will execute them in parallel. It becomes trivial to register [a task that depends on](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:task_dependencies) both of these tasks and performs the operation you need.

If `runSuite1` and `runSuite2` are in parallel and their execution time really would benefit from running them in parallel, see if you can move one of the tasks to a different project.

Comment: The intention is mainly to run the programs in parallel where all tasks are under single project. Thanks for your suggestion @Louis Jacomet